# How to split a string in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a `varchar @a='a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p'`, which has `|` delimited values. I want to split this variable in a array or a table.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a table valued function like this,

```
CREATE FUNCTION Splitfn(@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return      

end
```

and get your variable and use this function like this,

```
SELECT i.items FROM dbo.Splitfn(@a,'|') AS i
```

Comment: @gbn does table of numbers execute faster than a loop.... Please explain a bit more...

Comment: Please see my links in my answer

Comment: There are more elegant solutions out there but when supporting legacy code bases from SQL 2005 and below this is the only choice

Comment: should you cleanup the temp table that is returned from the function?

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is such a common question here

I'll give the common answer: [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum) by Erland Sommarskog

I'd recommend a [table of numbers](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum), not a loop, for general use.

Comment: Perhaps you could improve the answer by explaining how to apply this method to split a text at each delimiter. =)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
declare @a varchar(10) 
set @a = 'a|b|c|'
while len(@a) > 1
begin
insert into #temp
select substring(@a,1,patindex('%|%',@a)-1);
set @a = substring(@a,patindex('%|%',@a)+1,len(@a))
end;
```

Comment: Nice solution, but need to clarify - it's important that string should be ended with delimiter symbol. If it won't - you will fall into infinite cycle

Comment: my extension to your solution is to add this clause after your "set @a" row:

IF(patindex('%|%',@a)=0) 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO #temp select @a; 
 BREAK;
END;

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative XML based solution. It seems to have a similar performance as the Splitfn() solution.

This converts varchar `a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p` into XML `<a>a</a><a>b</a><a>c</a><a>d</a><a>e</a><a>f</a><a>g</a><a>h</a><a>i</a><a>j</a><a>k</a><a>l</a><a>m</a><a>n</a><a>o</a><a>p</a>` and extracts the value from each XML `<a>` node.

```
declare @a      varchar(max);
set @a  =   'a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p';

declare @xml    xml;
set @xml    
    =   '<a>'+replace(replace(replace(@a,'&','&amp;'),'<','&lt;'),'|','</a><a>')+'</a>';

SELECT  x.n.value('.','VARCHAR(1)') AS  singleValue
FROM    @xml.nodes('/a') AS  x(n)
;
```