# SQL Counting occurrences of document keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops, count, keyword

I'm trying to work out the most efficient way to count the number of occurrences that a keyword appears in my document table based on a specific list of document ids passed into my stored procedure.

The SP takes a parameter `@DocIds` as a comma seperated list e.g. 100, 2010, 2340

What I am wanting to do is select the records where the DocID exists in the comma seperated list I'm passing in and records the keywords into a temporary table but also keep a count if the keyword has already been added to my temp table.

So for example (document table):

```
DocID | Keywords
-----------------------------
100   | Test, Document, Info
2010  | Document, users
4     | ....    
2340  | users, client
```

Temp table would return:

```
Keyword  | Count
Test     | 1
Document | 2
Info     | 1  
users    | 2
client   | 1
```

I'm sure some SQL guru has a great solution for this any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
M

Comment: You should include the Database and Version since solutions for parsing comma seperated fields are highly dependent on this.

Comment: Good call - I'm using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution for SQL Server 2005+. It uses a recursive CTE to produce the counts of words

Sample data and temp table creation

```
CREATE Table #Temp ([Count] int, Keyword varchar(max) );

DECLARE @document AS TABLE ( 
  docid    INT, 
  keywords VARCHAR(MAX)) 

INSERT INTO @document 
VALUES      (100, 'Test, Document, Info'), 
            (2010, 'Document, users'), 
            (4, '....'), 
            (2340, 'users, client')
```

Query

```
 ; WITH cte(docid, word, keywords) 
         AS (SELECT docid, 
                    LEFT(keywords, Charindex(',', keywords + ',') - 1), 
                    Stuff(keywords, 1, Charindex(',', keywords + ','), '') 
             FROM   @document 
             UNION ALL 
             SELECT docid, 
                    LEFT(keywords, Charindex(',', keywords + ',') - 1), 
                    Stuff(keywords, 1, Charindex(',', keywords + ','), '') 
             FROM   cte 
             WHERE  keywords > '') 
    INSERT INTO #Temp ([Count], Keyword)
    SELECT COUNT(docid), 
           Ltrim(Rtrim(word)) 
    FROM   cte 
    GROUP  BY Ltrim(Rtrim(word)) 

    SELECT [Count], Keyword FROM #temp
```

Output

```
Count       Keyword
--------    -----
1           ....
1           client
2           Document
1           Info
1           Test
2           users
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to run a query for each keyword

```
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ('users',(
   SELECT COUNT(DocID) FROM Documents WHERE keywords LIKE '%users%')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2189860818012), has a technique for selecting out of a keyword list.
With that technique, and a GROUP BY keyword, you can get the COUNT(*)
which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the input dude - I should have mentioned as pointed out above I'm using Sql Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, look at one of the many answers for splitting a string into individual rows eg [How to split a string in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786377/how-to-split-a-string-in-t-sql)

Then your steps are:
1. Parse the list of relevant doc ids into a temporary table (@selectedDocs) using this function (may need a data type conversion)
2. Populate another temporary table (@keywords) with the keywords used by these documents:

    `insert into @keywords (docID, keyword)

    select d.docID, ltrim(rtrim(words.s))

    from @selectedDocs sd

    inner join @documents d on d.docID = sd.docID

    cross apply (select * from dbo.Split(',', d.keywords)) words`


3. Count how many times each keyword is used:

    `select k.keyword, count(k.docID)

    from @keywords k

    group by k.keyword`

Note that you'd use a table variable usually only where you're expecting a few answers or a temporary table for more.