# Delete from table, and return the records which weren't deleted

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have an table at my SQLSERVER(2008R2) called "Clients" , it has ClientID and Address.
I'd like to make a query/SP which does the following:

1. Recieves a list of addresses.
2. Deletes the records with these address.
3. Returns a list of the addresses that can't be deleted(row not found, etc).
4. Returns the number of deleted rows.

My application is C#-ASP.NET based application.
I've thought of the following solutions:

1. Make an `SP` that recieves a list of addresses, and then tries to delete them, and if it can't delete it , to add it to some sort of array/list. - my problem with this solution is that I'm not familiar with how lists works at SQLSERVER(2008R2).
2. Work with `DataTable` , select the data I need from the DB, and delete it with `SqlDataAdapter`, and check whats the rows which have changed via `RowState`.

Example of my DataBase:

```
Client ID    Address

111111111  'foo st. 2'

222222222  'foo bld 1'

333333333  'foo rd 22'

444444444  'foo st. 1'
```

Example of the input:

`input list{'foo st. 2','foo bld 1','foo st 22','foo st 1'}` - the last two items aren't exist at the table above, So i would like my SP (or any other method of solution) to return:

```
'Deleted rows: 2' //thats not a problem
'list of the records which weren't removed: {'foo st 22','foo st 1'} //thats a problem..
```

Hope I made myself as clear as possible.

Comment: `DataRow.RowState` does only reflect the state in the datatable not in the datatbase. So after you've updated the DataTable via SqlDataAdapter, the [rowstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx) will be `Unchanged` since the adapter called `AcceptChanges` as the last step.

Comment: Yeah, Just tried to implement it and I saw it wasn't a good idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can find which items aren't deleted by a delete statement in sql. Firstly you need a way to split your string by comma's. I'd use a table function like what's suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786377/how-to-split-a-string-in-t-sql)

once you have that then you need to select before you delete into a temp table, then delete the records that are there, then return the missing records:

```
DECLARE @SplitString TABLE
(
    value varchar(MAX)
)

DECLARE @MissingRecords TABLE
(
    value varchar(MAX)
)


INSERT INTO @SplitString
SELECT  part
FROM    dbo.fSplitString('foo st 22, foo st 1', ',')



SELECT  value
FROM    @SplitString
WHERE   value NOT IN (  SELECT Address
                        FROM TableName
                     )

DELETE  FROM TableName
WHERE   Address IN (SELECT Value FROM @SplitString)

SELECT  *
FROM    @MissingRecords
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, execute the DELETE statement:

```
sql="DELETE FROM TABLENAME where Col1='Something'";
```

And then after execute SELECT statement to list of rows which are not deleted?

```
 sql="SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where Col1='Something'";
```

EDIT:

```
List<string> addresses=new List<string>()
{
 "foo st. 2","foo bld 1","foo st 22","foo st 1"
};
List<string> deleted=new List<string>();
List<string> notdeleted=new List<string>();

using(SqlConnection cn=new SqlConnection("connStr"))
 {
  using(SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand())
  {
    cmd.CommandText="DELETE from TableName Where Address=@address";
    cmd.Connection=cn;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@address",SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
    cn.Open();
    for(String address in addresses)
     {
       cmd.Parameters["@address"].Value=address;
       int result=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       if(result!=-1)
        {
          //deleted
          deleted.Add(address);
        }
      else
        {
         //not deleted
         notdeleted.Add(address);
        }
     }
    cn.Close();
   }
 }
```

Comment: you can do both in a single trip to the server - more efficient

Comment: This won't tell you which records were not deleted if they were never in the database which was the original problem

Comment: @AVD ,Thanks for the Update, I've thought of this way, However often I'd have to delete 10k+ records, will it be efficient?

Comment: since you can delete them all in one go, it seems like a lot of trips to the database