# T-SQL A problem while passing CSV string into a stored procedure

Tags: t-sql

I have that procedure which returns rows associated by ID with passed argument, i.e 1,5,7,9

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_data]
 @MyCodes as varchar(max) = ''
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @query as nvarchar(max)

 set @query = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE id IN (@p_MyCodes)'

 exec SP_EXECUTESQL @query,
                        N'@p_MyCodes varchar(max)', 
                        @p_MyCodes = @MyCodes
END
```

That procedure generates an error : **Error converting data type varchar to numeric.** when I pass as an argument e.g. 3,7,5

What's wrong ?

Comment: Check out: http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is going to accomplish what you are expecting it to.  The error you are getting is because it can't convert the string '3,7,5' to a number (note that it is NOT trying to parse out your individual values).

Two ways to get what you want:

1) Create a table value function that takes a CSV string and returns the results (I'm sure there are many on the web; Here's a related question: [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)).  This is nice because you can get rid of the SP_EXECUTESQL sproc call entirely; Your query becomes:

```
SELECT name FROM user where id IN (SELECT value FROM dbo.f_Split(@p_MyCodes))
```

2) Change your set to something like:

```
set @query = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE id in (' + @p_MyCodes + ')'
```

I don't recommend #2, it offers a SQL injection hole.

Comment: I used the 2nd option, but then I needed to change the 'exec' clausule into: exec SP_EXECUTESQL @query,                        N'@p_MyCodes nvarchar(max)','' and then everything worked perfetly :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass the ID list as parameter. You could create the SQL statement by concatenating:

```
set @query = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE id IN (' + @MyCodes + ')'
exec SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Though, this disables any kind of execution plan re-usage and enables SQL injection

A better solution would be to split the list into a temp table (or table variable) and using a JOIN. Last year, I wrote a blog post about different ways to split strings in T-SQL:
http://florianreischl.blogspot.com/2009/09/high-performance-string-split-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a comma separated string with the `in` operator, you have to use the actual values. So, you either have to split the string up and put the values in a temporary table, or concatenate the string into the query:

```
set @query = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE id IN (' + @p_MyCodes + ')'
```

Note that this opens up a potential security hole for SQL injection. You should not do this if you don't have full control over where the string comes from.