# syntax error in stored procedure when passing string containing space

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

When I pass `@param1` with space separated values, like `N'here it is'`, there is a syntax error. If no spaces in the middle, for example `N'hereitis'`, there is no such syntax error. Any ideas what is wrong?

I call stored procedure in this way,

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[foo]
  @param1 = N'here it is',
  @param2 = 10,
  @param3 = 10
```

Error message is

> message 7630, level 15, status 3, there is syntax error near 'here it is'.

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM (
         SELECT count(*) over() AS [Count],
                 *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by t.indexfoo ASC ) AS rowNum 
         FROM   dbo.tablefoo t        
         WHERE  contains(t.col1,@param1) 
         OR     contains(t.col2,@param1) 
         OR     contains(t.col3,@param1)
      ) tt 
 WHERE  tt.rowNum between @param2 and  @param3 + @param2-1
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Give an example of how you are calling the procedure.

Comment: that won't even compile anyway, where the comma's after each param in the signature?

Comment: HI RPM1984, what do you mean "where the comma's after each param in the signature"? Could you let me know which part of store procedure do you mean?

Comment: Hi Adam, I have provided how I call this store procedure. Please see my updated post. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that this error is occurring at the [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187787%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) operator.

SQL Server expects that multi-keywords will be separated by boolean operators (`AND` or `OR`) or surrounded in quotes.

```
WHERE CONTAINS(Name, ' "Mountain" OR "Road" ')
```

You'll have to split out each term.

For more information, see the [TSQL CONTAINS()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187787%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) MSDN documentation, looking in particular at the Examples section -- particularly interesting might be *Item J. Using CONTAINS to verify a row insertion*.

To work around, I'd suggest either:

- try pass in the search terms pre-formatted: `' "here" AND "it" AND "is" '`. I'm unsure if this will actually work.
- with your nvarchar as `'here it is'`, build a new string within the stored proc after [split that string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql) on the space, and build up a new string formatted as `CONTAINS()` requires.

Comment: Thanks. So, your suggestion is I should manually separate each keyword by space? For example, change contains (NAME, N'here it is') to contains (NAME, 'here' or 'it' or 'is')?

Comment: @George: unfortunately, yes. Obviously you've got a variable, which makes sense in the real world, and unfortunately that's how `CONTAINS` works.

Comment: Thanks p.campbell! Looks like I need to find a good to use SQL split and concat string function? Could you recommend an easy to use method? I read the links you mentioned, but seems long to read. :-)