# Group by space separated values and count them

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains messages taken for our clients and I basically need to find the top 50 list of the most commonly used words.

The table is called `Messages`, the typed message is `Message`. Effectively I want to `SELECT` all rows, recursively split each `Message` by space to get all words, `GROUP BY` each word and `COUNT` them. I'm struggling on recursively splitting by a space - any ideas?

Comment: You don't recursively split...splitting is linear.

Comment: splitting is linear only if you have a recusive function to split it. So you do need recusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (userID INT,MESSAGE NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT '1','word1 word2 word3' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','word2 word5 word4' UNION ALL
SELECT '2','word5 word2 word1' UNION ALL
SELECT '2','word1 word2 word3'

; WITH c AS(
SELECT N.Value,COUNT(N.Value) Cnt FROM 
@Table T
CROSS APPLY
dbo.split(T.message,' ') N
GROUP BY N.Value
)
SELECT  c.Value,c.Cnt
FROM    c
ORDER BY Cnt DESC
```

Result:

[image]

Note: you need split function which you can find in numerous examples in Internet. As exapmple, see here: [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)