# How to use CROSS APPLY XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, cross-apply

How can I use `CROSS APPLY` and `FOR XML` to normalise the table which contains a list for informartion?

```
Product Orderid
P1        1,2,3
P2        1,3
P3        1
```

It should be normalised like below

```
P1   1
P1   2
P1   3
P2   1
P2   3
P3   1
```

I think it can be done with `CROSS APPLY FOR XML`. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Lots of potentially relevant info in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql

Comment: @Michael : Thanks for editing. U made it meaningfull. Tanq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tested and working:

```
SELECT * INTO #T
FROM (
  SELECT 'P1' Product, '1,2,3' OrderId
  UNION SELECT 'P2', '1,3'
  UNION SELECT 'P3', '1') x;

WITH S AS (
  SELECT product, x.t
  FROM #T cross apply
       (select convert(xml, N'<root><r>' + replace(orderid,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>') t) x
)
SELECT s.Product, r.value('.', 'int') OrderId
FROM s cross apply t.nodes('//root/r') as records(r);

DROP TABLE #T;
```