# T-SQL Split String Like Clause

Tags: sql

I have `declare @a varchar(100) = 'abc bcd cde def'`. What I need is to select from a table where a column is like 'abc' or 'bcd' or 'cde' or 'def'. I can use a split function and a `while` to get what I want, but somewhere I saw a smart solution using `replace` or something similar and I just can't remember it.

I know I can use an xml variable, and parse it that way. However, the value is part of a large procedure, and the best way for me is to use it in string form.

I know I can solve this by building a dynamic sql query, but that is not an option in the domain I'm working in.

Comment: i cant see any other solution except split...

Comment: Are you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql or are you have trouble doing an `IN` on the results of the split?

Comment: There are tons of solutions, xml datatype, dinamyc queries, Im just looking for the one I need.

Comment: You're looking for something you forgot and can't really describe.   Good luck :)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql

Comment: how many sections do you have?= always 4

Comment: From 1 to n. =\ Search field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, I just can remember the solution. Its a hack, a little dirty trick that do the job.

Anyways, I ll use the code bellow (Im over SQL Server 2008), is it a good idea? I prefer it over the dirty split. Is it more performatic?

```
declare @w varchar(100) = 'some word'
declare @f xml

set @f = '<word>' + replace(@w, ' ', '</word><word>') + '</word>'

select
    template.item.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as word
from @f.nodes('/word') template(item)
```

Comment: Test it and see.  If you get results you don't understand, then ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

In tsql you can use a pattern `col like '[abcd]'`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

For matching multiple words (not letter) and without dynamic SQL, you'll have to get the values into a temp table. For a split function try this page http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#iterative and look at the List of Strings function iter_charlist_to_table.

Or maybe you are thinking of this little trick [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause/337817#337817) from the SO CEO.

Comment: Note: This matches individual characters.  If you wanted to match words, this wouldn't work.

Comment: I think you nailed it. Let me take a deep look. Thankx. What do you think about my dirty xml based technique?

Comment: personally I'd do the split-to-table function, but I never really used xml variable in sql server so I can't say which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function to split the individual items into a table, one record per item.  Then you simply join to that table.

```
insert into #FilterTable (filters)
select Items from dbo.Split(@YourFilterString)

select * 
  from YourTable yt
  join #FilterTable f on f.filters = yt.YourColumn
```

Of course my example is using equality.  It gets more complicated if you truly intend to use "like" with wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

for 4 sections max

```
WHERE
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@a, ' ', '.'), 1) = 'xxx'
    OR
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@a, ' ', '.'), 2) = 'xxx'
    OR
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@a, ' ', '.'), 3) = 'xxx'
    OR
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(@a, ' ', '.'), 4) = 'xxx'
```