# Set variable value to array of strings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to set a variable as a string of values. E.g.

```
declare @FirstName char(100)
select @FirstName = 'John','Sarah','George'

SELECT * 
FROM Accounts
WHERE FirstName in (@FirstName)
```

I'm getting a syntax error in the line `select @FirstName = 'John','Sarah','George'`:

```
Incorrect syntax near ','
```

Is there any way I can set the variable with many values?

Comment: Does your example contain 3 different SQL statements or only 1? Also what SQL are you using? In addition it would help if you could give is near which of those lines the incorrect syntax is near.

Comment: I think the question is basically "Does SQL Server support arrays?" and I believe the answer is no, but I'll wait for a SQL Server expert to comment.

Comment: @MikeChristensen, I am not declaring myself as an expert but no, SQL Server does not support arrays

Comment: If you're asking questions like this, you should specify which database you're using, as syntax and support changes - for instance, SQL Server might accept something that MySQL doesn't (and vice versa). The tag `SQL` is too generic for specific SQL questions.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql

Comment: @FilipPopović - It's not a duplicate if you don't know what the reference to `split` means in order to search for it.

Comment: @KenWhite, You are right, it is not duplicate since OP didn't ask for splitting string but using arrays in SQL Server. My bad.

Comment: Your question is misleading. The `Incorrect syntax near ','.` message is generated if you use `SET`, not `SELECT`, to assign the variable. If you use `SELECT`, the message is quite different: `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to assign three separate string literals to a single string variable. A valid string variable would be `'John, Sarah, George'`. If you want embedded single quotes between the double quotes, you have to escape them.

Also, your actual `SELECT` won't work, because SQL databases won't parse the string variable out into individual literal values. You need to use dynamic SQL instead, and then execute that dynamic SQL statement. (Search this site for `dynamic SQL`, with the database engine you're using as the topic (as in `[sqlserver] dynamic SQL`), and you should get several examples.)

Comment: Another approach is to parse into a TEMP table then join on that.

Comment: @Mike: True, but a) that requires parsing first, and b) if the user doesn't know how to assign to a string variable (not counting the `SET` error), the parsing would probably be a little much, and I wouldn't know how to suggest a search for that example. Good point, though.

Comment: What is the difference between SET and SELECT? I thought you could use either.

Comment: @HL8: [SET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx) sets the value of a local variable directly, while [SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx) requires you to `DECLARE` the variable first separately. They're similar, but not interchangeable.

Comment: @HL8: Re SET vs SELECT: Ken is mistaken. Both SET and SELECT require the variable to be declared, so there's no difference in that. In fact, for the purpose of this particular question the two are most likely interchangeable, though in general, as Ken correctly points out, they each indeed have their own specifics.

Comment: One big difference between set an select would be the where clause which from my understanding would not work with a set statement but will with a select statement. Please Correct Me If I Am Wrong.

Comment: @Richard: No, the where will not work on either of them. See my last paragraph above.

Answer (score 64):

```
declare  @tab table(FirstName  varchar(100))
insert into @tab   values('John'),('Sarah'),('George')

SELECT * 
FROM @tab
WHERE 'John' in (FirstName)
```

Comment: This should probably be the selected answer because it does exactly what the OP seems to be asking for.

Comment: This `SELECT * FROM @tab` is strange! We don't want to select from the variable we just declared, we want to `select from Accounts`
The "in" is deceiving and basically an "=" since FirstName only holds one value per row in `@tab`. The `SELECT FROM Accounts` from lavazza_or_jps's answer shows what's wanted and works fine

Answer (score 7):

```
-- create test table "Accounts"
create table Accounts (
  c_ID int primary key
 ,first_name varchar(100)
 ,last_name varchar(100)
 ,city varchar(100)
 );

insert into Accounts values (101, 'Sebastian', 'Volk', 'Frankfurt' );
insert into Accounts values (102, 'Beate',  'Mueller', 'Hamburg' );
insert into Accounts values (103, 'John',  'Walker', 'Washington' );
insert into Accounts values (104, 'Britney', 'Sears', 'Holywood' );
insert into Accounts values (105, 'Sarah', 'Schmidt', 'Mainz' );
insert into Accounts values (106, 'George', 'Lewis', 'New Jersey' );
insert into Accounts values (107, 'Jian-xin', 'Wang', 'Peking' );
insert into Accounts values (108, 'Katrina', 'Khan', 'Bolywood' );

-- declare table variable
declare @tb_FirstName table(name varchar(100));
insert into  @tb_FirstName values ('John'), ('Sarah'), ('George');

SELECT * 
FROM Accounts
WHERE first_name in (select name from @tb_FirstName);

SELECT * 
FROM Accounts
WHERE first_name not in (select name from @tb_FirstName);
go

drop table Accounts;
go
```

Answer (score 6):

A quick way to turn your varchar variable to a table (array of values) is to have your FirstName variable as a whole varchar first and then use the STRING_SPLIT method.

```
declare @FirstName varchar(100)
select @FirstName = 'John,Sarah,George'

SELECT * 
FROM Accounts
WHERE FirstName in (SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT(@FirstName, ','))
```

Comment: this! and in case STRING_SPLIT is not available for your database version, you can use this custom method; https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/18391068
this function worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL` you can not have a variable array.
However, the best alternative solution is to use a [temporary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables).

Answer (score 1):

I just want to extend @Code Save's answer

```
--collection table is required, since we cannot use directly arrays in TSQL
declare  @CollectionTable table(FirstName  varchar(100))
insert into @CollectionTable   values('John'),('Sarah'),('George')

SELECT * FROM TargetTable
WHERE Name IN (SELECT * FROM @CollectionTable)
```

In this way we can use the result from the `SELECT` statement from our `@CollectionTable` to be evaluated in the `IN` operator. And of course we can re-use the `@CollectionTable` as many times as we need.