# T-SQL split string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, split

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 column containing a string which I need to split by a comma. I have seen many answers on StackOverflow but none of them works in R2. I have made sure I have select permissions on any split function examples. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is one of the million answers that I like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1846561/227755

Comment: What do you mean "none of them work"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Andy did point me in the right direction as I was executing the function incorrectly. This is why none of the other stack answers worked. My fault.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

Comment: There's a `mdq.RegexSplit` function in the "Master Data Services" add-on, which may help. Certainly [worth investigating](https://thefirstsql.com/2011/02/07/regular-expressions-advanced-string-matching-and-new-split-function-sql-server-2008-r2/).

Answer (score 293, accepted):

I've used this SQL before which may work for you:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
```

and to use it:-

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring('91,12,65,78,56,789')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy. I made a small enhancement to your script to allow the function to return an item at a specific index in the split string. It is useful only in situations when you the structure of the column one is parsing. https://gist.github.com/klimaye/8147193

Comment: I posted some improvements (with backing test cases) to my github page [here](https://github.com/MPagel/StackExchangeAnswers/blob/master/tSQL/2008R2/splitstring.sql.md). I will post it as an answer in this [so] thread when I have enough rep to exceed post "protection"

Comment: Great answer. Also works on earlier versions of SQL Server, such as 2005, which one of my clients is still using.

Comment: Although this is a great answer, it is outdated... Procedural approaches (especially loops) are something to avoid... It's worth to look into newer answers...

Comment: This doesn't work for `select * from dbo.splitstring('')`

Comment: Its too slow when testing with large input. Use native STRING_SPLIT or use another implementation like using XML, as its is faster.

Comment: I totally agree with @Shnugo. The looping splitters work but horribly slow. Something like this http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ is far better. Some other excellent set based options can be found here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: This function trims the trailing space for the last string

Comment: I couldn't use this as is, but it gave me the right guidance and the right mindset to find my own solution -- that means your code was my muse and you inspired me, so you get my upvote and my undying gratitude as a fellow scripter.

Answer (score 79):

Instead of recursive CTEs and while loops, has anyone considered a more set-based approach? Note that this function was written for the question, which was based on SQL Server 2008 and **comma as the delimiter**. In SQL Server 2016 and above (and in compatibility level 130 and above), [`STRING_SPLIT()` is a better option](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/t-sql-queries/string-split).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString
(
  @List     nvarchar(max),
  @Delim    nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
      CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
    FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
      FROM sys.all_columns) AS x WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], DATALENGTH(@Delim)/2) = @Delim
    ) AS y
  );
GO
```

If you want to avoid the limitation of the length of the string being <= the number of rows in `sys.all_columns` (9,980 in `model` in SQL Server 2017; much higher in your own user databases), you can use other approaches for deriving the numbers, such as building your own [table of numbers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11564/1186). You could also use a recursive CTE in cases where you can't use system tables or create your own:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString
(
  @List     nvarchar(max),
  @Delim    nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN ( WITH n(n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n+1 
       FROM n WHERE n <= LEN(@List))
       SELECT [Value] = SUBSTRING(@List, n, 
       CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, n) - n)
       FROM n WHERE n <= LEN(@List)
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, n, DATALENGTH(@Delim)/2) = @Delim
   );
GO
```

But you'll have to append `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` (or `MAXRECURSION <longest possible string length if < 32768>`) to the outer query in order to avoid errors with recursion for strings > 100 characters. If that is also not a good alternative then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595834/61305) as pointed out in the comments, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69541144/61305) if you need an *ordered* split string function.

(Also, the delimiter will have to be `NCHAR(<=1228)`. Still researching why.)

More on split functions, why (and proof that) while loops and recursive CTEs don't scale, and better alternatives, if you're splitting strings coming from the application layer:

- [Splitting strings](https://sqlblog.org/split)

Comment: There is a small bug in this procedure for the case where there would be a null value at the end of the string - such as in '1,2,,4,' - as the final value is not parsed.  To correct this bug, the expression "WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)" should be replaced with "WHERE Number <= LEN(@List) + 1".

Comment: @SylvainL I guess that depends on what behavior you want. In my experience, most people want to ignore any trailing commas as they don't really represent a real element (how many copies of a blank string do you need)? Anyway, the *real* way to do this - if you'll follow the second link - is to step messing around with splitting big ugly strings in slow T-SQL anyway.

Comment: Like you have said, most people want to ignore any trailing commas but alas, not all. I suppose that a more complete solution would be to add a parameter to specify what to do in this case but my comment is just a little note to make sure that no one forget about this possibility, as it can be quite real in many cases.

Comment: I have a weird behavior with that function. If I use directly a string as a parameter -- it works. If I have a varchar, it does not. You can reproduce easily: 
declare invarchar as varchar
set invarchar = 'ta;aa;qq'
SELECT Value from [dbo].[SplitString](invarchar, ';')
SELECT Value from [dbo].[SplitString]('ta;aa;qq', ';')

Comment: I like this approach, but if the number of objects returned by `sys.all_objects` is less than number of the characters in the input string then it will truncate the string and values will go missing. Since `sys.all_objects` is just being used as a bit of a hack to generate rows, then there are better ways to do this, e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39595834/767314).

Comment: The one thing I don't understand is: Why the outermost CTE? It seems like you're doing `SELECT [Value] FROM (SELECT [Value] = ... FROM ...)`, so it seems like the outer `SELECT [Value] FROM` is redundant. Is there a performance consideration I'm not seeing?

Comment: @Justin so that you can choose to return the second column (e.g. for troubleshooting, sorting, etc).

Comment: @knuckels thats why a numbers table is always handy!

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins I know you have probably long solved the problem by now, but I don't think your issue is the function's fault. Try this: `declare @x varchar; set @x = '123'; print @x;` and then [read this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @KMC It does now. FWIW most split functions won't work with space as a delimiter, because of how SQL Server handles trailing spaces (this question was specifically about comma as a delimiter, in SQL Server 2008). But if you're on 2016 or better, [just use `STRING_SPLIT()` anyway](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/t-sql-queries/string-split).

Answer (score 76):

Finally the wait is over in **SQL Server 2016** they have introduced Split string function : [**`STRING_SPLIT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt684588.aspx)

```
select * From STRING_SPLIT ('a,b', ',') cs
```

All the other methods to split string like XML, Tally table, while loop, etc.. has been blown away by this `STRING_SPLIT` function.

Here is an excellent article with performance comparison : [**Performance Surprises and Assumptions : STRING_SPLIT**](http://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/t-sql-queries/string-split)

Comment: obviously answers question of how to split string for those with updated servers, but those of us still stuck on 2008/2008R2, will have to go with one of the other answers here.

Comment: You need to take a look at the compatibility level in your database. If it is lower than 130 you won't be able to use the STRING_SPLIT function.

Comment: Actually, if the compatibility isn't 130 and you're running 2016 (or Azure SQL) you can set the compatibility up to 130 using:
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130

Comment: Note the documentation: "The output rows might be in any order." A third argument is added in SQL Server 2022 to return `ordinal` position with results.

Answer (score 34):

The easiest way to do this is by using `XML` format.

**1. Converting string to rows without table**

**QUERY**

```
DECLARE @String varchar(100) = 'String1,String2,String3'
-- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' to your desired one
DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR = ','    

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Value' 
FROM  
(     
     SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@String, @Delimiter, '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data            
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

**RESULT**

```
 x---------x
 | Value   |
 x---------x
 | String1 |
 | String2 |
 | String3 |
 x---------x
```

**2. Converting to rows from a table which have an ID for each CSV row**

**SOURCE TABLE**

```
 x-----x--------------------------x
 | Id  |           Value          |
 x-----x--------------------------x
 |  1  |  String1,String2,String3 |
 |  2  |  String4,String5,String6 |     
 x-----x--------------------------x
```

**QUERY**

```
-- To change ',' to any other delimeter, just change ',' before '</M><M>' to your desired one
DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR = ','

SELECT ID,LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) 'Value' 
FROM  
(     
     SELECT ID,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(VALUE, @Delimiter, '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data            
     FROM TABLENAME
) AS A 
CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

**RESULT**

```
 x-----x----------x
 | Id  |  Value   |
 x-----x----------x
 |  1  |  String1 |
 |  1  |  String2 |  
 |  1  |  String3 |
 |  2  |  String4 |  
 |  2  |  String5 |
 |  2  |  String6 |     
 x-----x----------x
```

Comment: This approach will break if `@String` contains forbidden characters... I just posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42000063/5089204) to overcome this issue.

Comment: Best answer for me. Doesn't need a function ! Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I needed a quick way to get rid of the `+4` from a **zip code**.

```
UPDATE #Emails 
  SET ZIPCode = SUBSTRING(ZIPCode, 1, (CHARINDEX('-', ZIPCODE)-1)) 
  WHERE ZIPCode LIKE '%-%'
```

No proc... no UDF... just one tight little inline command that does what it must. Not fancy, not elegant.

Change the delimiter as needed, etc, and it will work for anything.

Comment: This isn't what the question is about. The OP has a value like '234,542,23' and they want to split it out into three rows ... 1st row: 234, 2nd row: 542, 3rd row: 23. Its a tricky thing to do in SQL.

Answer (score 7):

if you replace

```
WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit) > 0
```

with

```
WHILE LEN(@stringToSplit) > 0
```

you can eliminate that last insert after the while loop!

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE LEN(@stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit)


if @pos = 0
        SELECT @pos = LEN(@stringToSplit)


  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 RETURN
END
```

Comment: This would result in the last character of the last element being truncated. 
i.e. "AL,AL" would become "AL" | "A" 
i.e. "ABC,ABC,ABC" would become "ABC" | "ABC" | "AB"

Comment: appending `+1` to `SELECT @pos = LEN(@stringToSplit)` appears to address that issue. However, the `SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)` will return `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function` unless you add `+1` to the third parameter of SUBSTRING as well. or you could replace that assignment with `SET @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, 4000) --MAX len of nvarchar is 4000`

Comment: I posted some improvements (with backing test cases) to my github page [here](https://github.com/MPagel/StackExchangeAnswers/blob/master/tSQL/2008R2/splitstring.sql.md). I will post it as an answer in this [so] thread when I have enough rep to exceed post "protection"

Comment: I too have noted the issue pointed out by Terry above. But the given logic by  @AviG is so cool that it does not fail in the middle for a long list of tokens.
Try this test call to verify (This call should return 969 tokens)
    select * from   dbo.splitstring('token1,token2,,,,,,,,token969')
Then I tried the code given by mpag to check the results for same call above and found it can return only 365 tokens. 

Finally I fixed code by AviG above and posted the bug free function as a new reply below since comment here allows only limited text. Check reply under my name to try it.

Answer (score 7):

The often used approach with XML elements breaks in case of forbidden characters. This is an approach to use this method with any kind of character, even with the semicolon as delimiter.

The trick is, first to use `SELECT SomeString AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')` to get all forbidden characters properly escaped. That's the reason, why I replace the delimiter to a *magic value* to avoid troubles with `;` as delimiter.

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE (ID INT, SomeTextToSplit NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES
 (1,N'A&B;C;D;E, F')
,(2,N'"C" & ''D'';<C>;D;E, F');

DECLARE @Delimiter NVARCHAR(10)=';'; --special effort needed (due to entities coding with "&code;")!

WITH Casted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST(N'<x>' + REPLACE((SELECT REPLACE(SomeTextToSplit,@Delimiter,N'§§Split$me$here§§') AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),N'§§Split$me$here§§',N'</x><x>') + N'</x>' AS XML) AS SplitMe
    FROM @Dummy
)
SELECT Casted.ID
      ,x.value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Part 
FROM Casted
CROSS APPLY SplitMe.nodes(N'/x') AS A(x)
```

The result

```
ID  Part
1   A&B
1   C
1   D
1   E, F
2   "C" & 'D'
2   <C>
2   D
2   E, F
```

Answer (score 5):

All the functions for string splitting that use some kind of Loop-ing (iterations) have bad performance. They should be replaced with set-based solution.

This code executes excellent.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Comment: This approach will break if `@List` contains forbidden characters... I just posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42000063/5089204) to overcome this issue.

Comment: I'm upvoting your response because yours work with space as delimiter and highest voted one doesn't

Answer (score 2):

I had to write something like this recently. Here's the solution I came up with. It's generalized for any delimiter string and I think it would perform slightly better:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
    ( @string nvarchar(4000)
    , @delim nvarchar(100) )
RETURNS
    @result TABLE 
        ( [Value] nvarchar(4000) NOT NULL
        , [Index] int NOT NULL )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str nvarchar(4000)
          , @pos int 
          , @prv int = 1

    SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string)
    WHILE @pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @str = SUBSTRING(@string, @prv, @pos - @prv)
        INSERT INTO @result SELECT @str, @prv

        SELECT @prv = @pos + LEN(@delim)
             , @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string, @pos + 1)
    END

    INSERT INTO @result SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, @prv, 4000), @prv
    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution using a CTE, if anyone should need that (apart from me, who obviously did, that is why I wrote it).

```
declare @StringToSplit varchar(100) = 'Test1,Test2,Test3';
declare @SplitChar varchar(10) = ',';

with StringToSplit as (
  select 
      ltrim( rtrim( substring( @StringToSplit, 1, charindex( @SplitChar, @StringToSplit ) - 1 ) ) ) Head
    , substring( @StringToSplit, charindex( @SplitChar, @StringToSplit ) + 1, len( @StringToSplit ) ) Tail

  union all

  select
      ltrim( rtrim( substring( Tail, 1, charindex( @SplitChar, Tail ) - 1 ) ) ) Head
    , substring( Tail, charindex( @SplitChar, Tail ) + 1, len( Tail ) ) Tail
  from StringToSplit
  where charindex( @SplitChar, Tail ) > 0

  union all

  select
      ltrim( rtrim( Tail ) ) Head
    , '' Tail
  from StringToSplit
  where charindex( @SplitChar, Tail ) = 0
    and len( Tail ) > 0
)
select Head from StringToSplit
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need a quick ad-hoc solution for common cases with minimum code, then this recursive CTE two-liner will do it:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(200) = ',1,2,,3,,,4,,,,5,'

;WITH
a AS (SELECT i=-1, j=0 UNION ALL SELECT j, CHARINDEX(',', @s, j + 1) FROM a WHERE j > i),
b AS (SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, i+1, IIF(j>0, j, LEN(@s)+1)-i-1) s FROM a WHERE i >= 0)
SELECT * FROM b
```

Either use this as a stand-alone statement or just add the above CTEs to any of your queries and you will be able to join the resulting table `b` with others for use in any further expressions.

### edit (by Shnugo)

If you add a counter, you will get a position index together with the List:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(200) = '1,2333,344,4'

;WITH
a AS (SELECT n=0, i=-1, j=0 UNION ALL SELECT n+1, j, CHARINDEX(',', @s, j+1) FROM a WHERE j > i),
b AS (SELECT n, SUBSTRING(@s, i+1, IIF(j>0, j, LEN(@s)+1)-i-1) s FROM a WHERE i >= 0)
SELECT * FROM b;
```

The result:

```
n   s
1   1
2   2333
3   344
4   4
```

Comment: I like this approach. I hope you don't mind, that I added some enhancement directly into your answer. Just feel free to edit this in any convenient way...

Answer (score 2):

I take the xml route by wrapping the values into elements (M but anything works):

```
declare @v nvarchar(max) = '100,201,abcde'

select 
    a.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
from
    (select cast('<M>' + REPLACE(@v, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) as col) as A
    CROSS APPLY A.col.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more narrowly-tailored.  When I do this I usually have a comma-delimited list of unique ids (INT or BIGINT), which I want to cast as a table to use as an inner join to another table that has a primary key of INT or BIGINT.  I want an in-line table-valued function returned so that I have the most efficient join possible.

Sample usage would be:

```
 DECLARE @IDs VARCHAR(1000);
 SET @IDs = ',99,206,124,8967,1,7,3,45234,2,889,987979,';
 SELECT me.Value
 FROM dbo.MyEnum me
 INNER JOIN dbo.GetIntIdsTableFromDelimitedString(@IDs) ids ON me.PrimaryKey = ids.ID
```

I stole the idea from http://sqlrecords.blogspot.com/2012/11/converting-delimited-list-to-table.html, changing it to be in-line table-valued and cast as INT.

```
create function dbo.GetIntIDTableFromDelimitedString
    (
    @IDs VARCHAR(1000)  --this parameter must start and end with a comma, eg ',123,456,'
                        --all items in list must be perfectly formatted or function will error
)
RETURNS TABLE AS
 RETURN

SELECT
    CAST(SUBSTRING(@IDs,Nums.number + 1,CHARINDEX(',',@IDs,(Nums.number+2)) - Nums.number - 1) AS INT) AS ID 
FROM   
     [master].[dbo].[spt_values] Nums
WHERE Nums.Type = 'P' 
AND    Nums.number BETWEEN 1 AND DATALENGTH(@IDs)
AND    SUBSTRING(@IDs,Nums.number,1) = ','
AND    CHARINDEX(',',@IDs,(Nums.number+1)) > Nums.number;

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a correct version on here but I thought it would be nice to add a little fault tolerance in case they have a trailing comma as well as make it so you could use it not as a function but as part of a larger piece of code. Just in case you're only using it once time and don't need a function. This is also for integers (which is what I needed it for) so you might have to change your data types.

```
DECLARE @StringToSeperate VARCHAR(10)
SET @StringToSeperate = '1,2,5'

--SELECT @StringToSeperate IDs INTO #Test

DROP TABLE #IDs
CREATE TABLE #IDs (ID int) 

DECLARE @CommaSeperatedValue NVARCHAR(255) = ''
DECLARE @Position INT = LEN(@StringToSeperate)

--Add Each Value
WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @StringToSeperate) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @Position  = CHARINDEX(',', @StringToSeperate)  
    SELECT @CommaSeperatedValue = SUBSTRING(@StringToSeperate, 1, @Position-1)

    INSERT INTO #IDs 
    SELECT @CommaSeperatedValue

    SELECT @StringToSeperate = SUBSTRING(@StringToSeperate, @Position+1, LEN(@StringToSeperate)-@Position)

END

--Add Last Value
IF (LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@StringToSeperate)))>0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #IDs
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@StringToSeperate, 1, @Position)
END

SELECT * FROM #IDs
```

Comment: if you were to `SET @StringToSeperate = @StringToSeperate+','` immediately before the `WHILE` loop I think you might be able to eliminate the "add last value" block.  See also my sol'n [on github](https://github.com/MPagel/StackExchangeAnswers/blob/master/tSQL/2008R2/splitstring.sql.md)

Comment: Which answer is this based on? There are a lot of answers here, and it's a bit confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I modified +Andy Robinson's function a little bit. Now you can select only required part from returning table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) )

RETURNS

 @returnList TABLE ([numOrder] [tinyint] , [Name] [nvarchar] (500)) AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)

 DECLARE @pos INT

 DECLARE @orderNum INT

 SET @orderNum=0

 WHILE CHARINDEX('.', @stringToSplit) > 0

 BEGIN
    SELECT @orderNum=@orderNum+1;
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX('.', @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @orderNum,@name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END
    SELECT @orderNum=@orderNum+1;
 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @orderNum, @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END


Usage:
```

`SELECT Name FROM dbo.splitstring('ELIS.YD.CRP1.1.CBA.MDSP.T389.BT') WHERE numOrder=5`

Answer (score 1):

Simples

```
DECLARE @String varchar(100) = '11,21,84,85,87'

SELECT * FROM TB_PAPEL WHERE CD_PAPEL IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String, ','))
-- EQUIVALENTE
SELECT * FROM TB_PAPEL WHERE CD_PAPEL IN (11,21,84,85,87)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a version that can split on a pattern using patindex, a simple adaptation of the post above. I had a case where I needed to split a string that contained multiple separator chars.

```
alter FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(1000), @splitPattern varchar(10) )
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE PATINDEX(@splitPattern, @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = PATINDEX(@splitPattern, @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
select * from dbo.splitstring('stringa/stringb/x,y,z','%[/,]%');
```

result looks like this

stringa
stringb
x
y
z

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I use this function :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CUST_SplitString]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1) 
        FROM Split
        WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a double Splitter (Takes two split characters) as requested [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024198/splitting-a-dynamic-string-in-t-sql/25028433#25028433). Could be of some value in this thread seeing its the most referenced for queries relating to string splitting.

```
CREATE FUNCTION uft_DoubleSplitter 
(   
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @String VARCHAR(4000), 
    @Splitter1 CHAR,
    @Splitter2 CHAR
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE (Id INT,MId INT,SValue VARCHAR(4000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @FResult TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                   SValue VARCHAR(4000))
DECLARE @SResult TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                   MId INT,
                   SValue VARCHAR(4000))
SET @String = @String+@Splitter1

WHILE CHARINDEX(@Splitter1, @String) > 0
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @WorkingString VARCHAR(4000) = NULL

       SET @WorkingString = SUBSTRING(@String, 1, CHARINDEX(@Splitter1, @String) - 1)
       --Print @workingString

       INSERT INTO @FResult
       SELECT CASE
            WHEN @WorkingString = '' THEN NULL
            ELSE @WorkingString
            END

       SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, LEN(@WorkingString) + 2, LEN(@String))

    END
IF ISNULL(@Splitter2, '') != ''
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @OStartLoop INT
       DECLARE @OEndLoop INT

       SELECT @OStartLoop = MIN(Id),
            @OEndLoop = MAX(Id)
       FROM @FResult

       WHILE @OStartLoop <= @OEndLoop
          BEGIN
             DECLARE @iString VARCHAR(4000)
             DECLARE @iMId INT

             SELECT @iString = SValue+@Splitter2,
                   @iMId = Id
             FROM @FResult
             WHERE Id = @OStartLoop

             WHILE CHARINDEX(@Splitter2, @iString) > 0
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @iWorkingString VARCHAR(4000) = NULL

                    SET @IWorkingString = SUBSTRING(@iString, 1, CHARINDEX(@Splitter2, @iString) - 1)

                    INSERT INTO @SResult
                    SELECT @iMId,
                         CASE
                         WHEN @iWorkingString = '' THEN NULL
                         ELSE @iWorkingString
                         END

                    SET @iString = SUBSTRING(@iString, LEN(@iWorkingString) + 2, LEN(@iString))

                END

             SET @OStartLoop = @OStartLoop + 1
          END
       INSERT INTO @Result
       SELECT MId AS PrimarySplitID,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MId ORDER BY Mid, Id) AS SecondarySplitID ,
            SValue
       FROM @SResult
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO @Result
       SELECT Id AS PrimarySplitID,
            NULL AS SecondarySplitID,
            SValue
       FROM @FResult
    END
RETURN
```

**Usage:**

```
--FirstSplit
SELECT * FROM uft_DoubleSplitter('ValueA=ValueB=ValueC=ValueD==ValueE&ValueA=ValueB=ValueC===ValueE&ValueA=ValueB==ValueD===','&',NULL)

--Second Split
SELECT * FROM uft_DoubleSplitter('ValueA=ValueB=ValueC=ValueD==ValueE&ValueA=ValueB=ValueC===ValueE&ValueA=ValueB==ValueD===','&','=')
```

**Possible Usage (Get second value of each split):**

```
SELECT fn.SValue
FROM uft_DoubleSplitter('ValueA=ValueB=ValueC=ValueD==ValueE&ValueA=ValueB=ValueC===ValueE&ValueA=ValueB==ValueD===', '&', '=')AS fn
WHERE fn.mid = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive cte based solution

```
declare @T table (iden int identity, col1 varchar(100));
insert into @T(col1) values
       ('ROOT/South America/Lima/Test/Test2')
     , ('ROOT/South America/Peru/Test/Test2')
     , ('ROOT//South America/Venuzuala ')
     , ('RtT/South America / ') 
     , ('ROOT/South Americas// '); 
declare @split char(1) = '/';
select @split as split;
with cte as 
(  select t.iden, case when SUBSTRING(REVERSE(rtrim(t.col1)), 1, 1) = @split then LTRIM(RTRIM(t.col1)) else LTRIM(RTRIM(t.col1)) + @split end  as col1, 0 as pos                             , 1 as cnt
   from @T t
   union all 
   select t.iden, t.col1                                                                                                                              , charindex(@split, t.col1, t.pos + 1), cnt + 1 
   from cte t 
   where charindex(@split, t.col1, t.pos + 1) > 0 
)
select t1.*, t2.pos, t2.cnt
     , ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTRING(t1.col1, t1.pos+1, t2.pos-t1.pos-1))) as bingo
from cte t1 
join cte t2 
  on t2.iden = t1.iden 
 and t2.cnt  = t1.cnt+1
 and t2.pos > t1.pos 
order by t1.iden, t1.cnt;
```

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect to @AviG this is the bug free version of function deviced by him to return all the tokens in full.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'TF' AND name = 'TF_SplitString')
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[TF_SplitString]
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:  AviG
-- Amendments:  Parameterize the delimeter and included the missing chars in last token - Gemunu Wickremasinghe
-- Description: Tabel valued function that Breaks the delimeted string by given delimeter and returns a tabel having split results
-- Usage
-- select * from   [dbo].[TF_SplitString]('token1,token2,,,,,,,,token969',',')
-- 969 items should be returned
-- select * from   [dbo].[TF_SplitString]('4672978261,4672978255',',')
-- 2 items should be returned
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TF_SplitString 
( @stringToSplit VARCHAR(MAX) ,
  @delimeter char = ','
)
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([Name] [nvarchar] (500))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @pos INT

    WHILE LEN(@stringToSplit) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@delimeter, @stringToSplit)


        if @pos = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @pos = LEN(@stringToSplit)
            SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos)  
        END
        else 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)
        END

        INSERT INTO @returnList 
        SELECT @name

        SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
    END

 RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Andy Robertson's answer, I needed a delimiter other than comma.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( @stringToSplit nvarchar(MAX), @delim nvarchar(max))
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE ([value] [nvarchar] (MAX))
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(max)
 DECLARE @pos INT

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@delim, @stringToSplit) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@delim, @stringToSplit)  
  SELECT @value = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos - 1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @value

  SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos + LEN(@delim), LEN(@stringToSplit) - @pos)
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @stringToSplit

 RETURN
END
GO
```

And to use it:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dbo.splitstring('test1 test2 test3', ' ');
```

(Tested on SQL Server 2008 R2)

EDIT: correct test code

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].func_split_string
(
    @input as varchar(max),
    @delimiter as varchar(10) = ";"

)
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
    id smallint identity(1,1),
    csv_value varchar(max) not null
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pos AS INT;
    DECLARE @string AS VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    WHILE LEN(@input) > 0
    BEGIN           
        SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(@delimiter,@input);

        IF(@pos<=0)
            select @pos = len(@input)

        IF(@pos <> LEN(@input))
            SELECT @string = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, @pos-1);
        ELSE
            SELECT @string = SUBSTRING(@input, 1, @pos);

        INSERT INTO @result SELECT @string

        SELECT @input = SUBSTRING(@input, @pos+len(@delimiter), LEN(@input)-@pos)       
    END
    RETURN  
END
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Use this function:

```
        CREATE FUNCTION SplitString
        (    
           @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
           @Character CHAR(1)
          )
            RETURNS @Output TABLE (
            Item NVARCHAR(1000)
          )
        AS
        BEGIN

      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT
      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

      WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
      BEGIN
            SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

            INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

            SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
      END

      RETURN
END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

**Here is an example that you can use as function or also you can put the same logic in procedure.
--SELECT * from [dbo].fn_SplitString ;**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString]
(@CSV VARCHAR(MAX), @Delimeter VARCHAR(100) = ',')
       RETURNS @retTable TABLE 
(

    [value] VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)AS

BEGIN

DECLARE
       @vCSV VARCHAR (MAX) = @CSV,
       @vDelimeter VARCHAR (100) = @Delimeter;

IF @vDelimeter = ';'
BEGIN
    SET @vCSV = REPLACE(@vCSV, ';', '~!~#~');
    SET @vDelimeter = REPLACE(@vDelimeter, ';', '~!~#~');
END;

SET @vCSV = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@vCSV, '&', '&amp;'), '<', '&lt;'), '>', '&gt;'), '''', '&apos;'), '"', '&quot;');

DECLARE @xml XML;

SET @xml = '<i>' + REPLACE(@vCSV, @vDelimeter, '</i><i>') + '</i>';

INSERT INTO @retTable
SELECT
       x.i.value('.', 'varchar(max)') AS COLUMNNAME
  FROM @xml.nodes('//i')AS x(i);

 RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: This approach will break if `@vCSV` contains forbidden characters... I just posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42000063/5089204) to overcome this issue.

Answer (score -1):

/*

> Answer to [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10914576/4228193)
>   Based on answers from [Andy Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10914602/4228193) and [AviG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13296353/4228193)
>   Enhanced functionality ref: [LEN function not including trailing spaces in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2025585/4228193)
>   This 'file' should be valid as both a markdown file and an SQL file

```
*/

    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.splitstring ( --CREATE OR ALTER
        @stringToSplit NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ) RETURNS @returnList TABLE ([Item] NVARCHAR (MAX))
    AS BEGIN
        DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @pos BIGINT
        SET @stringToSplit = @stringToSplit + ','             -- this should allow entries that end with a `,` to have a blank value in that "column"
        WHILE ((LEN(@stringToSplit+'_') > 1)) BEGIN           -- `+'_'` gets around LEN trimming terminal spaces. See URL referenced above
            SET @pos = COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @stringToSplit),0),LEN(@stringToSplit+'_')) -- COALESCE grabs first non-null value
            SET @name = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)  --MAX size of string of type nvarchar is 4000 
            SET @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, 4000) -- With SUBSTRING fn (MS web): "If start is greater than the number of characters in the value expression, a zero-length expression is returned."
            INSERT INTO @returnList SELECT @name --additional debugging parameters below can be added
            -- + ' pos:' + CAST(@pos as nvarchar) + ' remain:''' + @stringToSplit + '''(' + CAST(LEN(@stringToSplit+'_')-1 as nvarchar) + ')'
        END
        RETURN
    END
    GO

/*
```

Test cases: see URL referenced as "enhanced functionality" above

`SELECT *,LEN(Item+'_')-1 'L' from splitstring('a,,b')`

```
Item | L
---  | ---
a    | 1
     | 0
b    | 1
```

`SELECT *,LEN(Item+'_')-1 'L' from splitstring('a,,')`

```
Item | L   
---  | ---
a    | 1
     | 0
     | 0
```

`SELECT *,LEN(Item+'_')-1 'L' from splitstring('a,, ')`

```
Item | L   
---  | ---
a    | 1
     | 0
     | 1
```

`SELECT *,LEN(Item+'_')-1 'L' from splitstring('a,, c ')`

```
Item | L   
---  | ---
a    | 1
     | 0
 c   | 3
```

*/

Comment: rolled back to honor "This 'file' should be valid as both a markdown file and an SQL file"

Answer (score -3):

The easiest way:

1. Install SQL Server 2016
2. Use STRING_SPLIT https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt684588.aspx

It works even in express edition :).

Comment: Don't forget to set "Compatibility level" to SQL Server 2016 (130) - in management studio, right click on database, properties / options / compatibility level.

Comment: The original post said for SQL 2008 R2.  Installing SQL 2016 may not be an option