# Searching set of characters in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How to query if i want to check if string contains numbers(characters) like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in any order. It can be achieved by writing `AND` statements on `LIKE` clause for number 1,2..and so on like below,

```
Where days like '%1%' and days like '%2%' ...... So on
```

Is there any query which check specific characters present in string. or how above example can achieve with a short hand query. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is create a table with all the string you like to search.

e.g.

```
DECLARE  @searchstr TABLE (s VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @searchstr VALUES ('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7')

DECLARE  @tbl TABLE (days VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('1234567'),('123'),('1122334'),('7654321')  

SELECT   t.days 
FROM @tbl t
LEFT JOIN  @searchstr s 
        ON t.days LIKE '%' + s.s+ '%'
GROUP BY t.days HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.s) = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Will not [CONTAINS()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) work for you?

Also notice how to [split word into char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517816/t-sql-split-word-into-characters).

Comment: @eraj It would, but the thing is, you have to use full-text indexing to use this predicate.

Comment: @eraj: if you are using full-text for this, you need to remove those letters from stoplist, because otherwise it will search only words not letters..and also full-text search is not preferable for your requirement I suppose..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into `[PATINDEX][1]`. From MSDN:

> Returns the starting position of the first occurrence of a pattern in
>   a specified expression, or zeros if the pattern is not found, on all
>   valid text and character data types.

You probably will end up using something like `WHERE PATINDEX(%[0-9]%', foo) > 0`

Comment: PATINDEX return true when any characters in the string match with the expression. But i need all these characters(1234567) present in the string.

Comment: Then I misread the question. Not sure that would be possible without just using a bunch of AND statements :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use CHARINDEX

```
CHARINDEX(stringthatcontainschars1, '1', numofpositiontostartlookingat)
Output: 24, the position that your searched for char is at. returns zero if not found
```

if you were looking for the number 1 in a column or a string you would put:

```
CHARINDEX(columnname, '1', 1)
This would search for '1' beginning at position 1.
```

You can do an conditional statement based on whether or not it returns 0 to decide if char is in string or not and write whatever code you need after that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `isnumeric` to ensure they're all digits, then test for 0, 8, or 9 instead of 1-7 because it's shorter.

Answer (score -2):

If days are coma separated you can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(1, days) AND FIND_IN_SET(2, days);
```

It is different, not better, but as far as I know there is no other native way. 
And LIKEs probably will be much faster then find_in_set