# Check existence of each character in a string with another string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a string

```
@Str1 = '123'
```

I have another string

```
@Str2 = '12345'
```

I need to compare both strings and return *1* if each character in `@Str1` have an existence in `@Str2`

even If the `@Str2` is '45132' it must return 1,

If `@Str2` is *456* It must return *0*

Even If the @Str2 is '45132' it must return 1

I don't suggest use of any functions, because my live table has 1 million rows in it. Possibly I could avoid performance hit.

Comment: Are these strings different columns in your table?

Comment: Yes..I just simplified it with Variables

Comment: Apply to this what the answerer told you in How can I insert each character of a string to separate row in a table?

Comment: Are those columns int type or varchar(which may contain alphabets) ?

Comment: And does "34152" match "123"?

Comment: Yes, it must return 1 if the second string is "34152"

Comment: What about repeating?   Str1=112 amd Str2=12345   Is that a hit or miss?

Comment: It must be a hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @str1 VARCHAR(20) = '123'
declare @str2 VARCHAR(20) = '12345'


SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM master.dbo.spt_values V 
        WHERE V.type='P' 
            AND V.number    BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@str1)
            AND CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@str1, v.number, 1), @str2) = 0
    ) THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END
```

Comment: It seems an exact answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

One quick option is the sign() of charindex().  This will return 1 or 0.

```
Declare @Str1 varchar(25) = '123'
Declare @Str2 varchar(25) = '12345'

Select sign(charindex(@Str1,@Str2))
```

Returns

```
1
```

Comment: What if the second string is '14235' ?

Comment: @TinoJoseThannippara It will return 0

Comment: @TinoJoseThannippara Did I misread the question.  Are you looking for ALL individual characters?

Comment: Yes. 
If the second string is '14235' it must return 1.

Comment: @TheGameiswar  Updated

Answer (score 1):

Using what Zohar ansewered you in [How can I insert each character of a string which is not comma delimited to separate row in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654285/how-can-i-insert-each-character-of-a-string-to-separate-row-in-a-table#43654285)

you can use:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(X)=LEN(@STR) THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS ALL_PRESENT
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( SUBSTRING(@Str, Number, 1), @STR2) >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS X
    FROM Tally
    WHERE Number <= LEN(@Str)
    ) A
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(X)=LEN(@STR) THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS ALL_PRESENT
FROM (
    SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX( SUBSTRING(@Str, Number, 1), @STR2) >0 THEN 1 END AS X
    FROM Tally
    WHERE Number <= LEN(@Str)
    ) A
```

Output 
using

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(10)='123'
DECLARE @STR2 VARCHAR(10)='456123345'

ALL_PRESENT
-----------
1
```

Output using

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(10)='123'
DECLARE @STR2 VARCHAR(10)='45613345'

ALL_PRESENT
-----------
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming col1 is like @str1 and col2 is like @str2 then your query can be

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, CASE WHEN Col2 LIKE Col1+'%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM YourTable
```

W/o using any functions and adding for the case

> Even If the @Str2 is '45132' it must return 1

query can be like

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, CASE WHEN Col2 LIKE '%'+ Col1+'%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Even If the @Str2 is '45132' it must return 1, In this case it may return 0

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from (select '1928345' as Col1) as Table1
where Table1.Col1 like '%1%2%3%'
```