# SQL Server return column values contained in string

Tags: sql-server

I think I'm missing something simple here...

For example, given the word `absolutely`, return rows

```
absolute
absol
ab
absolutely
```

I tried `CONTAINS`

```
SELECT word
FROM [dbo].[SentimentModel1] 
WHERE contains(search,'absolutely')
```

Comment: SELECT word FROM [dbo].[SentimentModel1] WHERE columnN LIKE 'ab%'... What about something like this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is:

```
SELECT word FROM [dbo].[SentimentModel1] WHERE word LIKE '%absol%'
```

You should use the smaller part you want. That should generalize in some form.
A better way to do it is to use soundex:

```
SELECT word FROM [dbo].[SentimentModel1] WHERE SOUNDEX(word) = SOUNDEX('absol')
```

OR

```
SELECT word FROM [dbo].[SentimentModel1] WHERE SOUNDEX(word) = SOUNDEX('absolutely')
```

Another way you can do it is to split the word into characters: [T-SQL Split Word into characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517816/t-sql-split-word-into-characters)
After that all you need is to search the combination of characters.

the index position 0,

index position 0+1,

0+1+2,

etc...

For better performance you could add all the searches to a temporary table and index it. Full text search could be also helpful...

Comment: Hi @Kim - Thanks- unfortunately I can't abbreviate the word it needs to be 'absolutely'  I also can't have soundex as the match must be exactly the same as the start to the word...

Comment: Another way you can do it is to split the word into characters:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517816/t-sql-split-word-into-characters
After that all you need is to search the combination of characters. the index position 0, index position 0+1, 0+1+2, etc...

Comment: That would work Kim - I have lots of words to search, so the permutations are going to be large.  Was hoping for a more out-of-the-box approach.

Comment: Well, whats is the volume are we talking about? could you calculate all the permutations into a temporary table and index it? Full text search could help with that too...please let me know if that was helpful so I can update the answer...

Comment: Hi Kim,  yes permutations are huge and will be called many thousands of times - will need to have a good think about my options here.  Yes your suggestion is helpful - thanks.