# Display Sring in vertical manner

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have String like as follows

```
Declare @string ='welcome'
```

and i want output like this

```
w
e
l
c
o
m
e
```

Comment: What kind of output? A debug print or a string that is returned? Or smth else?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(256) = 'welcome'
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < len(@string)
BEGIN
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
    PRINT SUBSTRING ( @string ,@cnt , 1 )  
END;
```

In essence you loop through the length of the string.
You print the character at the location of the index of the loop and print that.

Comment: Yes it work fine 
and thank u

Comment: I have array of sting as 'chennai,mumbai,Bangalore,Hyderabad,pune'

--and i want to output like this

chennai
mumbai 
Bangalore
Hyderabad
Pune

what is the logic for this one bro

Comment: @KrishnaM I think you should refer to following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517816/t-sql-split-word-into-characters

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tally table for this, usually faster than looping, but you would have to test for yourself:

```
declare @s varchar(200)

set     @s = 'Welcome'


;with t as (
        select  v
        from    (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(v)
),
n as (
        select  row_number() over(order by (select null)) rn
        from    t t1 cross join t t2
)
select  substring(@s, rn, 1)
from    n
where   rn <= len(@s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca use recursive CTE.

```
Declare @string varchar(10) ='welcome'
;with cte as 
(
select 1 as i,substring(@string,1,1) as single_char
union all
select i+1 as i,convert(varchar(1),substring(@string,i+1,i+1)) as single_char from cte where len(convert(varchar(1),substring(@string,i+1,i+1)))=1
)
select single_char From cte
```