# Find Records That Haven't Specific Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table that it has a column `Name`. The user can specified some characters  So that the name column should not contain all those characters. How I can do this dynamically for unknown number of characters?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select name from tbl
except
select name from tbl
join
(select substring(a.b, v.number + 1, 1) letter
from (select 'WCRTV' b) a
join master..spt_values v on v.number < len(a.b)
where v.type = 'P') chars
on name like '%' + chars.letter + '%'
```

First, you take a `string` as the input, here the input is a static value `'WCRTV'` then using the following code, you can convert the `string` into a list of `chars` (the credit of this part goes to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8517932/2348125)):

```
select substring(a.b, v.number + 1, 1) letter
from (select 'WCRTV' b) a
join master..spt_values v on v.number < len(a.b)
where v.type = 'P'
```

Then you join the result with your table and finally subtract the result from the table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find names that contain the forbidden characters, then use `like`:

```
select name
from tbl
where name like '%[' + @forbidden_characters + ']%'
```

For example, if the characters to be ignored are numbers, then `@forbidden_characters` would contain `'0123455789'`.

If the characters were stored in a table instead, you can use `JOIN`:

```
select t.name, f.c
from t join
     @forbidden f
     on t.name like replace('%[<c>]%', '<c>', f.c);
```

Answer (score 0):

use regular expression with NOT LIKE "%[your charecter]%"

Comment: Ok Thanks but How?

Comment: you should pul all the char set inside [ ] .for example you have ''abc"' use it NOT LIKE [abc] ,if you have "abcd" use it [abcd].where is the confusion .please clear

Comment: consider these characters: `a` , `b` , `c` I want to select names that `NOT LIKE N'%a%' and NOT LIKE N'%b%' and NOT LIKE N'%c%'`

Comment: How about something like this... `WHERE colName not IN (''A","B", "C", ... )`

Comment: if your characters are a,b,c then it would be NOT LIKE "%[a|b|c]%"