# How to pass List of int value to SP from code behind?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I have a List of int in that i am getting some value now I want to pass all the value to my store procedure one by one or comma separated,

Code Behind:

```
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageId", IDList); //IDList is list of int which need to pass in my SP
```

in SP

```
@ImageId int //declaration

IF Not Exists(SELECT ImgIns.Id FROM ImgIns WHERE ImgIns.ImageId =@ImageId)
```

Comment: If you would like an alternative to passing a comma seperated list you could also serialise your list to XML and pass in the XML value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am passing the value one by one with the help of for loop and its working fine for me..

```
 for (int i = 0; i < IDList.Count; i++)
 {
    Cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageId", IDList[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing them in a comma separated string and split it in t-sql is the best option I found so far.

[Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql) will help for the split operation.

In Code Behind :

```
var IDList = String.Join(",", new List<int> {1,2,3});
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageIds", IDList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sql function to split the list of comma separated int http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648 insert this list into some table varibale and then you can wrtie your SP like

DECLARE @ImageIDs TABLE
(ImageID INT)

INSERT INTO @ImageIDs
select * from dbo.fn_Split(@ImageID)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ImageINstance I INNER JOIN @ImageIDs Img ON I.ImageID = Img.ImageID)