# Declare cursor in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, dynamic-sql

This code in a store procedure worked for years, now on the `OPEN` line I am getting *A cursor with the name ... does not exist*.

Did something change in `sp_executesql` that might have caused this to break?

Is there another way of doing this (the need for dynamic SQL is because the `@Types` param is passed in as a pre-formatted string for the `IN` clause?)

```
Select @Query = 'DECLARE cur_person CURSOR FOR
                 SELECT *
                 FROM MyTable
                 WHERE PersonID = @PersonnelID
                 AND Type in '  + @Types + '    <== formatted list for IN clause

EXEC sp_executesql @Query
OPEN cur_person                   <== get cursor doesn't exist error
```

Comment: There is a database option (`CURSOR_DEFAULT`) that controls whether cursors default to local or global when not explicitly specified. Maybe this has been changed your end hence the procedure suddenly breaking. In any event you could try explicitly declaring it as `GLOBAL`

Comment: Your way better off converting the in list to a table; `where type in dbo.someSplitFunc(@Types)` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql

Comment: Thanks to Martin - adding GLOBAL did the trick. All other solutions would be fine too I guess, but I didn't have the client code and had to make minimum changes to the proc to make things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, that means that the cursor is defined locally.

You can define it globally with database option (`CURSOR_DEFAULT`) but that might not be a good idea.

Another thing that you can do is put all code in the query and execute it.

Comment: Martin Smith was first with the GLOBAL option but it was a comment so I can't accept him :-(    This is next best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it fails, but here's a split function that avoids the need for the dynamic query:

CREATE FUNCTION StringToTable
(
    @p_list varchar(MAX),
    @p_separator varchar(5) = ',',
    @p_distinct bit = null
)
RETURNS 
@ParsedList table
(
    element varchar(500)
)
AS
BEGIN

```
DECLARE @v_element varchar(500), @Pos int, @v_insert_ind bit

SET @p_list = LTRIM(RTRIM(@p_list))+ @p_separator
SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@p_separator, @p_list, 1)

IF REPLACE(@p_list, @p_separator, '') <> ''
BEGIN
    WHILE @Pos > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @v_insert_ind = 1
        SET @v_element = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@p_list, @Pos - 1)))
        IF @v_element <> ''
        BEGIN
            IF (@p_distinct = 1)
            AND (SELECT count(element) FROM @ParsedList WHERE element = @v_element) > 0
                SET @v_insert_ind = 0
            IF @v_insert_ind = 1
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @ParsedList (element) 
                VALUES (@v_element)
            END
        END
        --
        SET @p_list = RIGHT(@p_list, LEN(@p_list) - @Pos)
        SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(@p_separator, @p_list, 1)
    END
END

RETURN
END
```