# Split function in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a string like `val1_val2,val3_val4` and I need to split these values to tabled data as follows.

```
column1 column2
 Val1     val2 
 Val3     val4
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Simple, question and requirement thats it. What you have tried??

Comment: @rizwanShahid, StackOverflow is a community where English  is the lingua franca since it's about IT, so please, let's stick with it

Comment: does val1_val2 have the same pattern, isn't there a val3, val4, etc?

Comment: @Adrian: It doesn't have any "," in between "val3,val4".

Comment: @Sai Kalyan Akshinthala: I tried to add my script, but its giving error, that why I didn't post my script here. Anyway Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A split function can [be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)

```
declare @str varchar(100) 
set @str = "val1_val2,val3_val4"


declare @str varchar(100) = 'val1_val2,val3_val4'

select substring(f.value, 0, charindex('_', f.value)) as val1
      ,substring(f.value, charindex('_', f.value) + 1, LEN(f.value) ) as val2
from dbo.fnSplitString(@str, ',') f
```

Comment: Hey, you gave very smart answer for me.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice answer here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str

Using this function you could just use:

```
SELECT fn_ParseText2Table 'val1_val2,val3_val4', '_'
```