# SQL: Parsing an associative input string with three delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I can do this using cursors, but I'm trying to avoid it if at all possible. Here's a bit of sample code that I've got going:

```
declare @string varchar(max) = 'person1:item1~item2~item3~etc^person2:item1~item2~item3~etc'

declare @table1 table (id int, value varchar(500))
declare @table2 table (id varchar(50), value varchar(500))
declare @table3 table (id varchar(50), value varchar(50))

insert @table1 (id, value) select * from fn_ParseDelimitedStrings(@string, '^')

insert @table2 (id, value) 
    select 
        id = (select f.value from fn_ParseDelimitedStrings(t.value, ':') f where f.RowId=1),
        value = (select f.value from fn_ParseDelimitedStrings(t.value, ':') f where f.RowId=2)
    from @table1 t

select * from @table2
```

The above code gives me the data in the form of:

```
id        value
-------------------------------
person1   item1~item2~item3~etc
person2   item1~item2~item3~etc
```

But I need the data in this form:

```
id        value
-------------------------------
person1   item1
person1   item2
person1   item3
person1   etc
person2   item1
person2   item2
person2   item3
person3   etc
```

The input string can have any number of "persons", and each person can have any number of "items".

**fn_ParseDelimitedStrings** is a custom function we have that returns a table of index-value pairs for each delimited item. ie:

```
RowID   Value
-------------
1       item1
2       item2
3       item3
4       etc
```

I'm having trouble associating each "item" from the final split to the "person" that they should be associated with.

Is there anything that can be done or am I going to have to use a cursor?

Comment: Check out this post . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql.  If you care about performance, look at what Aaron Bertrand has to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[outer apply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) will join current row with all the rows found in derived table inside outer apply:

```
insert @table2 (id, value) 
select 
    id = (select f.value from fn_ParseDelimitedStrings(t.value, ':') f where f.RowId=1),
    value = v1.value
from @table1 t
outer apply
(
  select v.value
    from fn_ParseDelimitedStrings(
         (select f.value 
            from fn_ParseDelimitedStrings(t.value, ':') f 
           where f.RowId=2)
         , '~') v 
) v1
```

*Edited value1 to v1 to match the outermost select