# How to work with CSV values in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, csv

I have CSV values stored in string as:

```
    StringBuilder CSValue = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < obj._contactNumbers.Count; i++)
    {
        CSValue.Append(obj._contactNumbers[i]);
        if (i != obj._contactNumbers.Count - 1)
        {
            CSValue.Append(",");
        }
    }
```

I have passed it to stored procedure (as CSValue.ToString()), now i have to pick each value and store it in cell. How should i seperate these values??

Please help me out!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this one

```
declare @Temp nvarchar(max), @c int, @a nvarchar(max)

declare @Temp_Table table (value nvarchar(max))

select @Temp = 'a,b,c,g,a'

select @c = CHARINDEX(',', @Temp)
while @c > 0
begin
    insert into @Temp_Table
    select LEFT(@Temp, @c - 1)

    select @Temp = right(@Temp, LEN(@Temp) - @c)
    select @c = CHARINDEX(',', @Temp)
end

select * from @Temp_Table
```

or you can write a table function to do this, if you need to do it often

Comment: Thanku, it works but if i want to add SNO as an attribute in table `@Temp_Table` so that i get the maximum number of rows present in the table, How should i serially add value in it???

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with SQL Server 2008, instead of a CSV, I would actually push them into an XML document as follows:

```
<Values>
    <Value value="1" />
    <Value value="2" />
    <Value value="3" />
</Values>
```

Then, in the stored procedure, I would retrieve each value as a separate row using the following SQL:

```
SELECT value.value('(@value)[1]', 'INT') as 'id' 
FROM @idList.nodes('/Values/Value') as T(value)
```

This result can be joined with any other table using normal SQL query joins and get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I have a split function defined.

There are several thorough Stack Overflow threads regarding this, e.g. [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)