# MSSQL fast update

Tags: c#, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization

I have Sql-query ike this:

```
UPDATE tProfile SET LastActivity=@DateTimeNow WHERE UserId=@UserId AND Id IN ({0})
```

Where {0} - it's a sting of id's, for example:

```
UPDATE tProfile SET LastActivity=@DateTimeNow WHERE UserId=@UserId AND Id IN (1155,1684,41368)
```

And this string can have couple thousands Id.

How I can do this query more easier, because this query using 100% CPU.

I want to know some alternates.

Comment: An interesting read: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html

Comment: What version of SQL Server? if 2008+ you can look at TVPs

Comment: Yes, 2008. Can you recommend some articles for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your IDs are a comma separated list then you could use a [split function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql) (UDF) to insert them into a table variable and then update.

```
DECLARE @IdTable TABLE (Id INT)
INSERT INTO @IdTable SELECT Id FROM dbo.SplitFunction(@IdList,',')

UPDATE p SET p.LastActivity = @DateTimeNow
FROM tProfile p INNER JOIN @IdTable i
  ON p.Id = i.Id
WHERE p.UserId = @UserId
```

Comment: So, best way to do it, like stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, you have to do the split function first.

Comment: Can you explain how to do SplitFunction?

Comment: Found this article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7938/SQL-User-Defined-Function-to-Parse-a-Delimited-Str), start reading...

Comment: I got it. I did SplitFunction and tried to use my program. I run my program, program finished, and was no UPDATE result. After that I repeat all steps in Management Studio, and all working. Why it's not working from program?

Comment: If your stored procedure call works from management studio, that means it works, problem could be in your program. Check it. may be wrong parameters.

Comment: Hm...I can't see any mistakes in my program, maybe some mistake in statement? Can you check this code please? http://pastebin.com/EBYs0K7c

Comment: Change `@IdList varchar` to `@IdList varchar(max)`

Comment: Thank you! That's was a problem! Little bit later I'll check performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp table containing these ids, then `UPDATE` with `JOIN` to this table. Something like:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.LastActivity=@DateTimeNow 
FROM tProfile t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 1115 Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1684
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 41368
    ...
) t2 ON t1.UserId = t2.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

As far i surfed net, IN shows slow performance... i would suggest to use JOIN of two tables... where 1st table will be the table which is to be updated and the second one will be the temporary table which holds all the Id values...
Then ur UPDATE query will look like 
`UPDATE tProfile tp 
INNER JOIN IdTable it ON tp.Id = it.Id 
SET LastActivity=@DateTimeNow 
WHERE UserId=@UserId`