# TSQL split string with ' '

Tags: t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split Function equivalent in tsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)

I have @FirstLastName = 'First Last'.

I need to split string in two variables @FirstName and @LastName.

In @FirstName goes 'First'.

In @LastName goes 'Last'.

Comment: Do you want something robust or will a combination of `CHARINDEX` + `SUBSTRING` suffice?

Comment: CHARINDEX + SUBSTRING will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick but it's only a **quick hack** ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8041)):

```
SET @FirstName = substring(@FirstLastName
                         , 1
                         , charindex(' ', @FirstLastName)-1)

SET @LastName = substring(@FirstLastName
                        , charindex(' ', @FirstLastName)
                        , 999)

-- if you want to calculate the actual @LastName length,
-- replace 999 with len(@FirstLastName)-charindex(' ', @FirstLastName)+1
```

For a **more elegant and robust way** see [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/95).