# SQL Query to return rows even if it is not present in the table

Tags: sql

This is a specific problem .

I have an excel sheet containing data. Similar data is present in a  relational database table. Some rows may be absent or some additional rows may be present. The goal is to verify the data in the excel sheet with the data in the table.

I have the following query

```
  Select        e_no, start_dt,end_dt
  From         MY_TABLE
  Where        e_no In 
  (20231, 457)
```

In this case,  e_no 457 is not present in the database (and hence not returned). But I want my query to return a row even if it not present (457 , null , null). How do I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

For `Sql-Server`: Use a temporary table or table type variable and left join `MY_TABLE` with it

**[Sql-Server fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5303/1)**

```
Declare @Temp Table (e_no int)

Insert into @Temp
Values (20231), (457) 

Select   t.e_no, m.start_dt, m.end_dt
From     @temp t left join MY_TABLE m on t.e_no = m.e_no
```

If your passing values are a csv list, then use a [split function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql) to get the values inserted to @Temp.

Comment: THAT'S how you insert multiple values!  Why could you not have written this 6 years ago?

Comment: @MikeBurton: What makes you to take it 6 years back? Oh btw, I wasn't a member of `stackoverflow.com` 6 years ago.

Comment: isnt `UNION` a better solution?

Comment: @Kaf: I was trying to work on a system with a fair-sized SQL DAL back then, and this would have come in handy for many, many things.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar: How could you use a `UNION`? You cannot use it for his requirement.

Comment: @Kaf either ways he just wants to populate data which is not present so i guess even a `UNION` would work in his case.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar, `UNION` doesn't work in this case, your below solution is a `hard coded query for a single value`.

Comment: @PraveenNambiar, no problem! I have added a demo above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply populate a temporary table in the database from your spreadsheet and join against that?  Any other solution is probably going to be both more work and more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way with a `UNION`

```
Select
     e_no, start_dt ,end_dt
From         MY_TABLE
Where e_no In (20231, 457) 

UNION

Select 457, null, null
```

Comment: What happen if he adds more `e_nos` to the list and (for example) 10 of them are not in `MY_TABLE`? And what about if `457` is actually in `MY_TABLE` ?