# Using IndexOf and/Or Substring to parse data into separate columns

Tags: t-sql, substring, indexof

I am working on migrating data from one database to another for a hospital. In the old database, the doctor's specialty IDs are all in one column (swvar_specialties), each separated by commas. In the new database, each specialty ID will have it's own column (example: Specialty1_PrimaryID, Specialty2_PrimaryID, Specialty3_PrimaryID, etc). I am trying to export the data out of the old database and separate these into these separate columns. I know I can use `indexof` and `substring` to do this - I just need help with the syntax.

So this query:

```
Select swvar_specialties as Specialty1_PrimaryID
From PhysDirectory
```

might return results similar to 39,52,16. I need this query to display `Specialty1_PrimaryID = 39`, `Specialty2_PrimaryID = 52`, and `Specialty3_PrimaryID = 16` in the results. Below is my query so far. I will eventually have a join to pull the specialty names from the specialties table. I just need to get this worked out first.

```
 Select pd.ref as PrimaryID, pd.swvar_name_first as FirstName, pd.swvar_name_middle as   MiddleName, 
 pd.swvar_name_last as LastName, pd.swvar_name_suffix + ' ' + pd.swvar_name_degree as NameSuffix, 
 pd.swvar_birthdate as DateOfBirth,pd.swvar_notes as AdditionalInformation, 'images/' + '' + pd.swvar_photo as ImageURL, 
 pd.swvar_philosophy as PhilosophyOfCare, pd.swvar_gender as Gender, pd.swvar_specialties as Specialty1_PrimaryID, pd.swvar_languages as Language1_Name 
 From PhysDirectory as pd
```

Comment: Only a comment but multiple columns for specialty is not 3rd normal form.  Should had a table with DrID, SpecialtyID so Dr can have zero or many specialties.

Answer (score 0):

The article [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql) provides some details on how to use a split function to split a comma-delimited string.

By modifying the table-valued function in presented in this article to provide an identity column we can target a specific row such as Specialty1_PrimaryID:

```
/*
    Splits string into parts delimitered with specified character.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SDF_SplitString]
(
    @sString nvarchar(2048),
    @cDelimiter nchar(1)
)
RETURNS @tParts TABLE (id bigint IDENTITY, part nvarchar(2048) )
AS
BEGIN
    if @sString is null return
    declare @iStart int,
        @iPos int
    if substring( @sString, 1, 1 ) = @cDelimiter 
    begin
        set @iStart = 2
        insert into @tParts
        values( null )
    end
    else 
        set @iStart = 1
        while 1=1
        begin
            set @iPos = charindex( @cDelimiter, @sString, @iStart )
            if @iPos = 0
            set @iPos = len( @sString )+1
            if @iPos - @iStart > 0          
            insert into @tParts
                values  ( substring( @sString, @iStart, @iPos-@iStart ))
            else
            insert into @tParts
                values( null )
            set @iStart = @iPos+1
            if @iStart > len( @sString ) 
            break
        end
    RETURN
END
```

Your query can the utilise this split function as follows:

```
Select 
    pd.ref as PrimaryID, 
    pd.swvar_name_first as FirstName, 
    pd.swvar_name_middle as   MiddleName, 
    pd.swvar_name_last as LastName, 
    pd.swvar_name_suffix + ' ' + pd.swvar_name_degree as LastName, 
    pd.swvar_birthdate as DateOfBirth,pd.swvar_notes as AdditionalInformation,
    'images/' + '' + pd.swvar_photo as ImageURL, 
    pd.swvar_philosophy as PhilosophyOfCare, pd.swvar_gender as Gender, 
    (Select part from SDF_SplitString(pd.swvar_specialties, ',') where id=1) as Specialty1_PrimaryID, 
    (Select part from SDF_SplitString(pd.swvar_specialties, ',') where id=2) as Specialty2_PrimaryID,
    pd.swvar_languages as Language1_Name 
From PhysDirectory as pd
```