# Handling Multiple Values in SS Reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a question, I have an SSRS report with multiple value field, I was just wandering how can I parse it from the SQL stored procedure that I have created eg.

```
Multiple Values -> Egg,Banana,Apple,Candies,Honey
```

SQL:

```
SELECT Qty, Amount FROM tblFoodList WHERE ListOfFood IN (?Multiple Values?)
```

How am I able to put the multiple values inside the IN CLAUSE, likewise is this the correct way, or is there any other way..

Should I pass it as a string like?

```
@varTemp = 'Egg','Banana','Apple','Candies','Honey' 

SELECT Qty, Amount FROM tblFoodList WHERE ListOfFood IN (@varTemp)
```

Btw, I'm using SQL 2008 R2, and the string manipulation approach for SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a stored procedure, SSRS will always pass a CSV list; there is no option for a table-valued parameter or anything like that.

So it will be a string that looks like `'Egg,Banana,Apple,Candies,Honey'`.

Next step is to turn this string into a some sort of table variable and use that in the `IN` clause; there are any numbers of techniques you can use here.

[Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html) has maintained a great list of techniques.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql) SO question has various alternatives, too.

If you embed the query directly in the report, you *can* reference the variable like `IN (@varTemp)`; it's essentially dynamic SQL so this will build the appropriate query. An alternative to consider if you don't feel like putting too much logic in an SP.