# How to pass string array of Columns as parameter to SQL Server Stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a comma delimited string with column names i.e.

`"Column1, Column2, Column3"` which will be passed as a parameter to the following stored procedure.

My Stored Procedure is as follows:

```
@ColNames VARCHAR(1000)

Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Column1, Column2, Column3) AS RowNum, 
Column1, Column2, Column3
INTO #Results
From Table A
```

I want to replace the above hardcoded column names with the parameter `@colNames`. This will include splitting the comma delimited parameter into the individual column names.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing so ?why do you want row_number ?what you are trying to do ?refer this for split function
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use dynamic SQL in this case and execute it with [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).
For example:

```
DECLARE @ColNames VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @ColNames ='Column1, Column2,...'

SET @sSQL = 'SELECT ' + @ColNames + ' FROM myTable....'

exec sp_executesql @sSQL
```

I also made a quick [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdf65/5) to this.

Comment: This is not correct, sql server will treat this passed string of column names as a string but not object names.

Comment: You don't need to pass `@ColNames` to that sp_executesql: the value is already embedded in `@sSQL`

Comment: @M.Ali Could you point out exactly what would be not working out? Testing this out really quick [@SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fdf65/5) seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE yourId (@columns VARCHAR(1000))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @s_query VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @s_query = 'Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ' + @columns + ') AS RowNum, ' + @columns + ' From A'

EXEC(@s_query)
END
```

this is for t sql syntax

If you need information on how to split a string, you may have a look on this thread : [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)