# Insert data from Excel sheet with multiple tabs into SQL Server into multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, excel, bulkinsert, bulk-load

Suppose there are 5 worksheets for 5 tables in SQL Server, how do I write a single code to insert bulk data from this 5 sheets to 5 tables in SQL Server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import an Excel file into SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610133/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server)

Answer (score -1):

You can do that through SSMS import feature or run query.The question has already answered here :

[How to import an Excel file into SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610133/how-to-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server)