# Updating SQL table with thousands of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a single MSSQL table that I need to update a column with different values.

To update a single record, I would use a query like this:

```
UPDATE products 
SET price = 2.08 
WHERE product_id = 'B22991-12'
```

I need to do this about 7,000 times, so how would I do this? The new prices are currently in a spreadsheet.

Comment: when you have no alghorothmen with criteria make a new table fill it up and join it

Comment: Need some clarification.  Where are the price and product id coming from?

Comment: Specify the DBMS you are using

Comment: When you execute this statement 7000 times, you will do it (about) 6999 times without any results.  You should share more details about the other (about) 6999 cases.

Comment: Use: [How can I import an Excel file into SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610133/how-can-i-import-an-excel-file-into-sql-server), and then the given answer.  Please, use [edit] if that does not solve your question, and improve the question to 1 specific problem. (Like: `problem is importing`, or `Problem is updating`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by having a table that holds the correct prices of your products. Let’s say product_new_prices.

```
UPDATE a
SET a.price = b.price
FROM products a
INNER JOIN product_new_prices b on a.product_id = b.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify your DBMS. But many of them support the UPDATE ... FROM  statement.

If your product table is like so:

```
CREATE TABLE products(prd_id,prdname,price)  AS
          SELECT 'B22991-12','bread'     ,1.08
UNION ALL SELECT 'B22991-13','butter'    ,1.09
UNION ALL SELECT 'B22991-14','marmalade' ,1.09
;
```

Create an update source table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE upds(prd_id,price)  AS
          SELECT 'B22991-12',2.08
UNION ALL SELECT 'B22991-13',3.09
UNION ALL SELECT 'B22991-14',4.09
;
```

And then:

```
UPDATE products t
  SET  price=s.price
FROM   upds s
WHERE  s.prd_id=t.prd_id;
```