# DatagridView C# Sum of columns

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

Hello I'm wondering how can I get the sum of a column according with the value in another column. For example I have a DatagridView like this

```
User   Value to sum
-------------------
User1       10
-------------------
User1       15
-------------------
User2       20
-------------------
User3       30
```

I want to know how can I get the sum for each user.

Expected output

```
User1: 25        
User2: 20     
User3: 30
```

So far I have the code for get the sum of all users but I don't know hot to get per user.

Thanks in advance for everyone.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
    total += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[ColumnN].Value);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the `DataGridView` as source, you can't use the source of the `DataGridView`? That's easier

Comment: Maybe if you compute the values in the query, you can group by user and use sum to compute the value.

Comment: The data source is an excel file that I loaded as DataTable in order to populate the DatagridView I don't know if there is the best way to do it, but it was the only one that I thought, How @Juan How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you can load the data from excel, store in sql server(or any database system you have) do the query to compute the values and the read the result of the query and present it in the grid.

Comment: Maybe this method can help you, but sometimes fails if the format is not correct. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150739/code-to-read-xlsx-sheet-into-a-table-in-a-sql-server-database

If you write a query like the one in the question you can do combine it with the group by and the sum to feed the grid or combine it with an insert to load the data to sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
var userSums = dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
    .Select(g => new { User = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) });
```

Comment: This just works like charm. Thank you very much Tim!

Answer (score 0):

If you extract your data as a list of pairs you can use the codes below:

```
        var data = new List <KeyValuePair<string, int>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "User1", 10 ),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "User1", 15 ),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "User2", 20 ),
            new KeyValuePair<string, int>( "User3", 30 )
        };

        var res = data.GroupBy(x => x.Key);

        foreach (var item in res)
        {
            var user = item.ToList();
            var sum = item.Sum(x => x.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(user[0].Key + " " + sum);
        }
```