# DataGrid Sum specific rows C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

many have asked a question similar to mine but my concept is different. I have a DataGrid connected to Sql where I correctly display the data. I have 2 columns Name and Price, but many names are the same and I would like to sum the price column of only the same names of the Name column.
Name Price
A     3
B     2
A     7
B     9

So I would like to Sum only B or A

Comment: can you please share some code statements?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            if (textBox1.Text  == "")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
  
                MessageBox.Show("Inserire Commessa!");
            }
            else
            {
                this.gestionaleTableAdapter1.cercareport(this.gestionaleSQLDataSet.Gestionale, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            }

i just use this code and the datagrid search in sql and with another button i create a report in pdf 
but now i need to sum some rows of the datagrid

Comment: Actually without backend code it's hard to give solution. Please check this, might be helpful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50626375/datagridview-c-sharp-sum-of-columns