# How to take apart information between hyphens in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How would I take apart a column that contains string:

92873-987dsfkj80-2002-04-11
20392-208kj48384-2008-01-04

Data would look like this:

```
Filename     Yes/No     Key
Abidabo      Yes        92873-987dsfkj80-2002-04-11
Bibiboo      No         20392-208kj48384-2008-01-04
```

Want it to look like this:

```
Filename     Yes/No     Key
Abidabo      Yes        92873-987dsfkj80-20020411
Bibiboo      No         20392-208kj48384-20080104
```

whereby I would like to concat the dates in the end as 20020411 and 20080104. From the right side, the information is the same always. From the left it is not, otherwise I could have concatenated it. It is not an import issue.

Comment: *Don't* store data like that in the first place. This string requires parsing, not splitting. Use a proper table with three different columns. You could write eg a regex to parse the original data, transform the fields to appropriate types and copy them to a proper table

Comment: The values look like fixed-width fields that came from some file. You could use any of SQL Server's import mechanisms to load a fixed-width file into a table, eg bcp, BULK INSERT, SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm correct and the date part is always on the right side of the string, you can simply use `RIGHT` and `CAST` to get the date (assuming, again, that the date is represented as `yyyy-mm-dd`):

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(YourColumn, 10) As Date)
FROM YourTable
```

However, Panagiotis is correct in his comment - You shouldn't store data like that. Each column in the database should hold only a single point of data, be it string, number or date.

**Update** following your comment and the updated question:

```
SELECT LEFT(YourColumn, LEN(YourColumn) - 10) + REPLACE(RIGHT(YourColumn, 10), '-', '')
FROM YourTable
```

will return the desired results.

Comment: I don't need it as date, but as a string like: 20020411. With the CAST(RIGHT(..)) it is still shown as 2002-04-11 (with hyphens) And I would like it without hyphens

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments already, storing data like this is a bad idea. However, you can obtain the dates from those strings by using a `RIGHT` function like so:

```
SELECT RIGHT('20392-208kj48384-2008-01-04', 10)
```

Output:

```
2008-01-04
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the SQLSERVER version you are using, you can use STRING_SPLIT which requieres COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL 130. You can also build your own User Defined Function to split the contents of a field and manipulate it as you need, you can find some useful examples of SPLIT functions in this thread:

[Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql)

Comment: You can't use STRING_SPLIT here, because the same character is used as a field *and* date separator