# Concatenate only the right side hyphens in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

How would I achieve the following in SQL Server?

Data looks like this:

```
Filename     Yes/No     Key
Abidabo      Yes        92873-987dsfkj80-2002-04-11
Bibiboo      No         20392-208kj48384-2008-01-04
```

Want it to look like this:

```
Filename     Yes/No     Key
Abidabo      Yes        92873-987dsfkj80-20020411
Bibiboo      No         20392-208kj48384-20080104
```

So that the hyphens would disappear ONLY for the dates in the end.

Comment: People have [already ansered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257621/how-to-take-apart-information-between-hyphens-in-sql-server) this question and explained that you shouldn't use such a schema. You just found another reason why.

Comment: Why don't you use three separate fields? If you are going to parse the values with each SELECT, why not fix the problem once and for all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take apart information between hyphens in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44257621/how-to-take-apart-information-between-hyphens-in-sql-server)

Comment: Modifying the un-normalized field isn't going to help. Each time you try to search for a date, or try to select the date part, you'll have to process the entire table and parse the field *again*. You can't use any indexes. Apart from fixing the schema, it would be better if you tried to create a persisted calculated field with an index.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `REPLACE` string functions.

**Query**

```
select *, 
left([key], len([key]) - 10) + replace(right([key], 10), '-', '')
from your_table_name;
```

You can use it for an `update` statement as well.

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/FYC19060)**

```
update [tblFiles]
set [key] = left([key], len([key]) - 10) + replace(right([key], 10), '-', '')
from [your_table_name];
```

And all `key` column values should be in the same manner.
I meant, should ends with `.........yyyy-mm-dd`

Answer (score 0):

```
;With cte([Filename],[Yes/No],[Key])
AS
(
SELECT 'Abidabo','Yes' ,'92873-987dsfkj80-2002-04-11' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bibiboo','No'  ,'20392-208kj48384-2008-01-04'
)
SELECT [Filename]
    ,[Yes/No]
    ,CONCAT(SUBSTRING([Key],0,LEN([Key])-9)
    ,REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Key], LEN(SUBSTRING([Key], 0, LEN([Key]) - 8)), LEN([Key])), '-', '')) AS ExpectedKey
FROM cte
```

OutPut

```
Filename     Yes/No     Key
-------------------------------------------------
Abidabo      Yes        92873-987dsfkj80-20020411
Bibiboo      No         20392-208kj48384-20080104
```