# Print Substring before and after slash '/' from a string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a task to print substring from a string based on the occurence of slash '/' position in a string .Below i'm trying to show you one sample example how i want to get .

```
Declare @My_string = 'abc/def gh /ijk l/m/no p/qr
```

From the above string i want to print the substring value based on the position of slash occourence.
**For Example:** Sometimes i was asked to print the substring after the 2nd occourence of slah then i've to display `ijk l` and Sometimes i was asked to print the substring after the 3rd occourence then `m` should display if it is 1st then `def gh`  vice versa .There is no specific occourence position it may vary based on need .How can i achieve it .Any help will be very thankful

**Note:** I want to achieve without using function .i know that it can be done by using split function .Is that possible to get without using it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split function equivalent in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql)

Comment: Which MS SQL version are you targeting? Azure SQL and SQL Server 2016 have STRING_SPLIT? For older versions, there are many answers.

Comment: Split the string into a table where one column is the index and the other is the text (so in your example `abc` will have index 0, `def gh` will have index 1 and so on. After that it's a plain and simple select statement.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i want to achieve without function .i know that it can be done by using spli function .is that possible to get without using it

Comment: Did you check the answers? Several do not declare functions.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Do we have any reference links for that approach .It will be helpfull for me if you share any links .

Comment: The best performing way is to import the function with CLR https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it without using a function is to use a recursive cte.
This is not the way I would recommend splitting a string but since you insist on not using a function it's a reasonable alternative.
If you change your mind about splitting string function, you should read Aaron Bertrand's [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) and choose a split string function that would be easy to modify to return the item number as well.

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @My_string varchar(100) = 'abc/def gh /ijk l/m/no p/qr',
        @SlashIndex int = 3
```

The CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  LEFT(@My_String, CHARINDEX('/', @My_String)-1) As Value,
            0 As SlashIndex,
            RIGHT(@My_String, LEN(@My_String) - CHARINDEX('/', @My_String)) As String
    WHERE CHARINDEX('/', @My_String) > 0
    OR LEN (@My_String) > 0

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT  LEFT(String, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', String) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('/', String) ELSE LEN(String) +1 END -1),
            SlashIndex + 1,
            RIGHT(String, LEN(String) -  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', String) > 0 THEN CHARINDEX('/', String) ELSE LEN(String) END)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE CHARINDEX('/', String) > 0 
    OR LEN(String) > 0
)
```

The Query:

```
SELECT Value
FROM CTE
WHERE SlashIndex = @SlashIndex
```

Result: `m`

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/KMVU44251)

Comment: Great !.it works but ,your code is little complex to understand .can't we make it little easy .one thing i've understood is you are doing using recursive cte .

Comment: Then check out Aaron's article I've linked to and adapt one of the functions he lists there. some of them are much simpler.

Comment: okay @Zohar Peled .. Thanks .one more thing if want to stick to a specific position like 1 or 2 or 3rd occurence will it be a good approach  .

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get the 3rd position via XML

Example

```
Declare @My_string varchar(max)= 'abc/def gh /ijk l/m/no p/qr'

Select Pos3 = convert(xml,'<x>'+replace(@My_String,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>').value('/x[3]','varchar(100)')
```

**Returns**

```
Pos3
ijk l
```

Comment: Here the third postion substring should be `m` beacuse `m`  is the substring after the third occurence of slash . And moreover can i pass position value using a variable or somehow .And also third position is not my fixed position to display .

Comment: @Mahesh.K With this approach, the first position (or string) would be abc.  Then perhaps a table-valued function to split the string

Answer (score 1):

created below function which will take 2 input first - your position and second will be your string and return the required output -

```
 create  function dbo.GetSubsting ( @StatPoint int , @Input_string varchar(1000) )
 returns varchar(1000)
 as 
 begin 
 Declare @len int , @idx int =1 , @section int = 1 , @output varchar(1000) = ''  
 DECLARE  @tab table   ( idx int identity(1,1 ), Val char(1) , section int )

 select @len = len(@Input_string)

 while @idx <= @len
 begin
 insert into @tab
 select substring( @Input_string , @idx ,1)  , @section
 if substring( @Input_string , @idx ,1) = '/'
 set @section = @section + 1
 set @idx = @idx + 1 
 end 

 select @output = @output + Val from @tab where section = @StatPoint 

 select @output = replace(@output , '/' , '')

 RETURN  @output
 end 
 go

 select dbo.GetSubsting(3, 'abc/def gh /ijk l/m/no p/qr')
 --OUTPUT 
 -- ijk l
```