# SQL split row contents to multiple rows

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Hello I am new to sql and 
I am not sure if it is possible like below

I have a row like this:

```
abc,xyz; bcd,ddd; qqq,eee
```

I want to write a query which will split the row to multiple rows like this:

```
abc,xyz
bcd,ddd
qqq,eee
```

Rows may contain 1 or 2 or 3 names or null, it is not fixed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Look at this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql
Instead of the comma being the delimiter, yours would be a semi colon.
Depending on the compatibility level set on your DB.. String_split may work as well

Answer (score 1):

Try some `XML` node methods which would turn your comma separated value into multiple rows

```
SELECT 
      LTRIM(a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')) [Data] FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(<column>, ';', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS DATA from <table_name>
) A CROSS APPLY DATA.nodes('/M') as split(a)
```

Result :

```
abc,xyz
bcd,ddd
qqq,eee
```

Comment: This is an old school way of leveraging the XML parsing in SQL.  You can also "bundle" this in a string split function for general use.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STRING_SPLIT ( fieldname, '; ')  
FROM tablename
```

or maybe you want a `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT z.field_a, z.field_b, x.VALUE
FROM tablename as z
CROSS JOIN (SELECT VALUE FROM STRING_SPLIT ( z.fieldname, '; ')) AS x
```

or maybe you want a `CROSS APPLY`

read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: It looks like the OP is using SQL Server 2008 or 2012, STRING_SPLIT only arrived in SQL Server 2016 as far as I know.

Comment: @AlanSchofield -- there are a million implementations of a string split function available with but a mighty web search.  The xml parse by Yogesh might be faster in some cases (and many implementations use it.)

Comment: I understand that but without stating the OP would have to create a UDF I was just clarifying the point.