# Not able to fetch Data from Stored Procedure IN Clause

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a store Procedure but not able to fetch the data from it.
Below is the Store Procedure.

```
USE test
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_IDs @idList nvarchar(1750)
AS
BEGIN TRY
SELECT DISTINCT child FROM example WHERE parent IN (@idList)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM example WHERE child IN (@idList)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber;
END CATCH
GO

EXEC SELECT_IDs @idList = ['100','101'];
```

After executing the above procedure it is giving me no data where as if i run the same select query it is giving me data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT child FROM example WHERE parent IN ('100','101')
```

After reading the comments i tried the below code but not working.

```
/*
Splits string into parts delimitered with specified character.
*/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SDF_SplitString]
(
@sString nvarchar(2048),
@cDelimiter nchar(1)
)
RETURNS @tParts TABLE ( part nvarchar(2048) )
AS
BEGIN
if @sString is null return
declare @iStart int,
        @iPos int
if substring( @sString, 1, 1 ) = @cDelimiter 
begin
    set @iStart = 2
    insert into @tParts
    values( null )
end
else 
    set @iStart = 1
while 1=1
begin
    set @iPos = charindex( @cDelimiter, @sString, @iStart )
    if @iPos = 0
        set @iPos = len( @sString )+1
    if @iPos - @iStart > 0          
        insert into @tParts
        values  ( substring( @sString, @iStart, @iPos-@iStart ))
    else
        insert into @tParts
        values( null )
    set @iStart = @iPos+1
    if @iStart > len( @sString ) 
        break
end
RETURN
END
```

And Modified the stored Procedure to

```
USE test
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_IDs @idList nVarchar(2048)
AS
BEGIN TRY
SELECT DISTINCT child FROM example WHERE parent IN ([dbo].[SDF_SplitString] 
('@idList',',')) or child IN ([dbo].[SDF_SplitString]('@idList',','))
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT parent FROM example WHERE parent IN ([dbo].[SDF_SplitString] 
(@idList,',')) or child IN ([dbo].[SDF_SplitString](@idList,','))
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber;
END CATCH
GO
```

But getting the issue : Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.SDF_SplitString", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: your code will not work. You have to use dynamic sql for the parameters you pass.

Comment: you can also used a table valued function to convert the comma separated list as a table variable and use that in the join clause with example.

Comment: TRYsplit function /TVP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **SQL Server 2016** and above, then try using `STRING_SPLIT`

```
USE test GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_IDs @idList nvarchar(1750) AS BEGIN TRY
    SELECT DISTINCT child
    FROM example
    WHERE parent IN
        (SELECT value
         FROM STRING_SPLIT(@idList, ','))
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT parent
    FROM example
    WHERE child IN
        (SELECT value
         FROM STRING_SPLIT(@idList, ',')) END TRY BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber; END CATCH 
GO

EXEC SELECT_IDs @idList = '100,101';
```

**UPDATE 1.0 - Integrating function for split**

Modify your `STORED PROCEDURE`as mentioned below, It seems you missed `SELECT` clause for the function call.

```
USE test GO
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECT_IDs @idList nVarchar(2048) AS BEGIN TRY
SELECT DISTINCT child
FROM example
WHERE parent IN (SELECT * FROM SDF_SplitString(@idList, ','))
  OR child IN (SELECT * FROM SDF_SplitString(@idList, ','))
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT parent
FROM example
WHERE parent IN (SELECT * FROM SDF_SplitString(@idList, ','))
  OR child IN (SELECT * FROM SDF_SplitString(@idList, ',')) END TRY BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber; END CATCH GO
```

Comment: Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: I guess you are using older version. This is available only and after SQL Server 2016. Refer https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split

Comment: So any idea how to achieve it without STRING_SPLIT

Comment: You have to create a custom function and use that. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Not able to do that...Below is the code which i tried

Comment: @PawanKumar I have updated the answer with function call