# Get data into different columns from single pipe separated column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have pipe separated data in one column pf table data something like this

[image]

I want to put that data in different column something like this

[image]

How to separate pipe separated data into different column is SQL?

I tried doing something like this

```
;WITH GRNSumm AS (
      SELECT Value
           ,ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Value)
      FROM   [Split]('asfasdjfsdg|sdhgs|sdg|sdgl','|')
    )
    SELECT 
    col1 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 1 THEN Value ELSE NULL END)
         , col2 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 2 THEN Value ELSE NULL END)
         , col3 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 3 THEN Value ELSE NULL END)
         , col4 = MAX(CASE WHEN ID = 4 THEN Value ELSE NULL END)
    into #tempdata
    FROM   GRNSumm
```

But it does not work for me

Comment: What does "it does not work for me" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you're using SQL Server 2017 and above you can use the table valued function [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like this:

```
select * from table1 outer apply string_split(col3, '|')
```

The problem now is, that you need to [pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) the rows to columns in order to get the pattern of your second table.

Now in your case it could look like this:

```
;WITH 
input_data as (
    select 1 col1, 1 col2, 'abc|bcd|asd|qwe' col3 union all
    select 1 col1, 2 col2, 'abc|dhejg|dlsjd|qwe' col3 union all
    select 2 col1, 3 col2, 'hdf|sjd|sdjf|sjdgs' col3 union all
    select 2 col1, 4 col2, 'asfasdjfsdg|sdhgs|sdg|sdgl' col3
),
GRNSumm AS (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, Value, Row_Number() OVER (partition by col1, col2 ORDER BY Value) id
    FROM   input_data outer apply [Split](col3, '|') --put string_split here or your own tvf
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, [1] as PackingSlip, [2] as ReceivingLog, [3] as DateReceived, [4] as GLExpenseAccount
  from GRNSumm
 PIVOT  
(MAX(Value) FOR id IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS PivotTable;
```

I say could, because now it gets tricky. The outer apply will not guarantee for any order of the rows depending on the position of the content. Moreover, the `row_number over (order by value)` will ensure that the order is dependent on the content and not the position of the string.

Comment: I am not using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: sql server 2014

Comment: but that does not work for multiple rows as I can not pas multiple data in spli function

Comment: The edit shows how it works with multiple rows for your case.

Comment: If you are using a older version, create your own function: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-t-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Your question suggests that you have a split function.  Unfortunately, the built-in split function in SQL does not have a position.

If you don't have duplicate values within a string, then you can use `charindex()` to identify the position:

```
WITH input_data as (
      select 1 col1, 1 col2, 'abc|bcd|asd|qwe' col3 union all
      select 1 col1, 2 col2, 'abc|dhejg|dlsjd|qwe' col3 union all
      select 2 col1, 3 col2, 'hdf|sjd|sdjf|sjdgs' col3 union all
      select 2 col1, 4 col2, 'asfasdjfsdg|sdhgs|sdg|sdgl' col3
     )
SELECT id.*, x.*
FROM input_data id CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN value END) as col4,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN value END) as col5,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 3 THEN value END) as col6,
             MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 4 THEN value END) as col7
      FROM (SELECT s.value,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX('|' + id.col3 + '|', '|' + s.value + '|')) as seqnum
            FROM string_split(id.col3, '|')  s
           ) x
     ) x;
```

Note that this approach does not have an outer aggregation (so it should be faster than doing an outer aggregation).  Instead, `APPLY` basically handles each row independently.

Comment: I do not have string_split function as I am not using sql server 2016 or later...

Comment: @vaibhavshah . . . Your question mentions a split function in the edit.  You can easily find one searching on the web